# Stack Overflow на русском – третий сайт сети Stack Exchange по количеству вопросов в день!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Продолжительное время наше сообщество Stack Overflow на русском занимает третье место среди профессиональных сообществ сети Stack Exchange по количеству задаваемых вопросов в день, одной из главных метрик активности любого сообщества.

## Поздравляю нас всех!

[image: Stack Overflow на русском – третий сайт сети]

**Спасибо! Спасибо каждому из нас!**

Спасибо от всех тех, кто получает развернутый ответ на свой вопрос, от всех тех, кто каждый день быстро находит готовое решение на сайте через поиск! За последние 30 дней сервис Google Analytics зарегистрировал на сайте 771 730 уникальных пользователей. Только представьте, мы помогли более чем 700 000 наших коллег, более 700 000 реальных людей воспользовались решениями из нашей русскоязычной базы знаний по программированию! Представьте, сколько тысяч человеко часов сэкономила собранная база знаний! И это только за последние 30 дней!

**Зачем вообще развиваться дальше?**

Развиваясь мы даем любому русскоязычному человеку возможность поделиться знаниями, вне зависимости от пола, возраста или материального положения. Каждый имеет возможность получить доступ к свободным знаниям. Каждый может получить качественный ответ от лучших разработчиков Рунета.

*Количество вопросов в день важно и потому, что показывает, сколько людей принимают решения довериться именно нашему сообществу в сложный для них момент. Это дорогого стоит.*

**Мы лишь в начале нашего увлекательного путешествия!**

Текущая активность сообщества достаточно велика, но, как мне кажется, мы не прошли и половины пути. Уверен, мы должны быть *как минимум* на одну позицию выше!

**Все это стало возможно благодаря Вам! Без Вас ничего бы не было и ничего не будет!**

Спасибо вам за ваш вклад в развитие русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков и энтузиастов программирования! В будущем нас всех ждет много всего интересного!

Comment: а мы разве уже не были третьим сайтом?

Comment: Математики, трепещите в ужасе! ))

Comment: @Grundy Нет. До этого мы были [четвертым сообществом сети](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3793/).

Comment: _Мы обогнали второй сайт трилогии_ - стали четвертыми - как-то запутанно все :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ещё бы понять выбор меток, тут [meta-tag:поддержка], там [meta-tag:обсуждение]. Может надо новый тег [meta-tag:вехи] или что-то подобное?

Comment: @Grundy второй (2), трилогии (3) - логично, что дальше идёт (4) - четвёртыми.

Comment: @alexolut, вторая трилогия - это два по три - в итоге шесть, и логично дальше идет 7 :)

Comment: Снова вижу несогласованное использование `Вы` :-D

Comment: За счёт светлого фона значка ruSO, он выглядит самым маленьким среди остальных, но, судя по результату, удаленьким.

Comment: Самый молодой и маленький, зато какой удаленький :) Что же, поздравляю всех! P. S. Минимум должен быть на 2 позиции выше!

Comment: Посмотрел на `visits-day / questions-day`. enSO 1177, Math 377, ruSO 303, Ubuntu 3155, SU 5234, L&U 3168. Интересная картина эффективности(?).  Т.е.  по количеству нашедших уже готовый ответ мы примерно как математики.