# Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?

Tags: обсуждение

Случается, участники сообщества дискутируют на тему качества имеющейся базы знаний и будущей (особенно в контексте [роста популярности сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4160/)).

На данный момент, насколько мне известно, не существует общепринятых критериев оценки. Как результат, каждый видит то, что хочет.

Пожалуйста, предложите ваши критерии оценки. По результатам обсуждения хотелось бы сформулировать более или менее простой численный способ оценки качества вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Возможно, я неверно понял вопрос. Нужны формализованные критерии, которые будет легко воплотить в программном коде для сбора численной аналитики?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, именно так. Можно выстроить теорию, но должна быть возможность ее проверить, желательно, через SEDE.

Comment: отличный вопрос в тему: [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

Answer (score 14):

Основной критерий качества это *полезность* для людей из поисковика, которые пытаются найти ответ на их вопрос по тематике сайта. Чем большему числу людей сайт помогает, тем лучше<sup>*</sup>.

Напрямую полезность измерить тяжело. Косвенно можно оценить полезность вопроса по количеству его просмотров (люди имеют такой вопрос *и* могут его найти) и наличию положительных голосов на ответах от последующих посетителей из поисковиков (индикация помог/не помог). Также можно следить за тем, сколько вопросов/ответов пришлось просмотреть человеку, прежде чем ответ удалось найти на сайте (меньше—лучше<sup>†</sup>).

Основной метод улучшения полезности это **повышение сигнал/шум отношения**. Практически весь существующий функционал на сайте на это направлен:

- фокус на вопросах/ответах (на самом содержимом, а не социальной составляющей: кто/какого автора больше любит—позволяет масштабировать сайт за пределы междусобойчика);
- возможность голосовать за вопросы/ответы (в среднем, хорошие ответы всплывают наверх страницы);
- возможность закрывать точные дубликаты (чтобы полезные ответы/обновления в одном месте собирать и чтобы опытные участники не износились/не устали на одни и те же вопросы отвечать);
- закрывать

  - неясные (нельзя ответить без магического кристалла),
  - слишком широкие (полезный ответ потребовал бы объёма книги)
  - или чересчур субъективные вопросы (позволяющие десятки ответов, не требующие ни знания предметной области ни практического опыта—много лёгкого шума с личными предпочтениями, вытесняющий полезные вопросы и людей, которые на них хотят ответить)
  - и соответствующие очереди проверок, ускоряющие процесс;
- очевидные вещи типа тревог для спама, агрессивных сообщений;
- возможность предлагать правки,
- оставлять комментарии к существующим сообщениям;
- отсутствие древовидных веток, поощряющих обсуждение вместо обновления самого ответа с полезной информацией, перенос в чат для сокрытия шума;
- подразумеваемая эфемерная роль самих комментариев (очевидно полезное содержимое желательно в сам вопрос/ответ помещать);
- метки, облегчающие поиск вопросов;
- знаки, позволяющие постепенно осваивать упомянутую функциональность/мягко поощряющие желаемое поведение на сайте, без необходимости всем тома документации изучать.

Чтобы всё это работало, в первую очередь *вопрос должен быть задан*. Если нет вопроса, то  веб-поисковику нечего индексировать -> меньше людей могут сайт найти -> меньше людей новые полезные вопросы могут задать (или потому что не знают о сайте или знают, но по такой репутации, что боятся спросить). Если полезный вопрос уже задан, то опытным участникам, не следует его закрывать (убирать сигнал), чтобы они не думали о лени автора. Роль автора, задать вопрос, который может быть полезен кому-то ещё, а не только автору. [Если вопрос полезен, то не имеет значения является ли он чьим-то домашним заданием](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044). Полезность вопроса можно оценить количеством людей, которые его имеют: [крайне простой вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/23044) типа [What does “SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'” mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445439/4279) является полезным, потому что более четверти миллиона просмотров у него. И наоборот: [стена кода с опечаткой не является хорошим вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044), поэтому есть стандартная причина закрытия для таких случаев.

Полезность вопроса улучшается, если *у вопроса есть одобренные ответы*: принятый или с плюсами ответ. Принятый ответ не значит, что ответ "правильный", но он говорит, что вероятно автор вопроса считает, что ответ ему помог. Аналогично, плюс (голос «за») говорит, что участник или несколько посетителей нашли этот ответ полезным. По опыту (10k+), большинство популярных/принятых ответов являются подходящими ответами (не самые лучшие, но и не откровенно вредные). Для популярных вопросов, с большим количеством ответов, в большинстве случаев, достаточно первые пару ответов посмотреть (принятый и следующий за ним популярный ответ). Нет необходимости листать одну за другой страницы с ответами. Для обычных вопросов хорошо, что авторам вопросов напоминают о принятии ответов, которые им помогли.

### [Конкретные метрики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/875/23044)

- вопросы должны быть (но сколько конкретно—это отдельный неочевидный вопрос): метрика [общее количество вопросов](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions)
- на них кто-то должен смотреть: метрика [traffic](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)
- они пользу должны нести: метрика [голосование](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/289002/total-number-of-votes-of?posttype=2&votetype=2), поведение на сайте (google analytics: если сигнал/шум отношение плохое, то безуспешно многочисленные Stack Overflow вопросы можно просматривать)
- желательно, чтобы ответы были качественные (это тяжело измерить, многие посетители не смогут распознать) демонстрировать *лучшие современные практики* для решения указанной в вопросе проблемы и соответственно вопросы желательно быть интересными: метрика [количество активных участников](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341448/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph), [количество опытных участников, которые остаются](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341457/active-experts-100-burnout-rate-after-a-year-by-default?year=2016&week=26&comparisonGap=1.0) (предполагая, что более опытные участники в среднем способны лучше качество оценивать решения).
- доброжелательность/отсутствие грубости/агрессии/осмеяния новых пользователей, незнакомых со спецификой сайта: метрика количество людей, задающих более одного вопроса (предполагается, что это к лучшим вопросам ведёт в перспективе)

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> это отличается и может конфликтовать с целью сделать определённую выбранную группу людей более счастливыми.

<sup>†</sup> в этом существенное отличие технического сайта от других сайтов таких как социальной сети. Мы хотим чтобы люди получали желаемый ответ как можно быстрее, не посещая десятки страниц.</sub>

Comment: Большое спасибо! Отличные метрики. Комментарий к метрике «трафик»: количество переходов из поиска на сайт на количество имеющихся вопросов в базе ниже почти в два раза чем на SOen и SOpt. Это большая проблема, которая возникла, как мне кажется, из за наличия двух поисковых систем в Рунете, одна из которых (Яндекс) не индексирует адекватно ни один сайт Stack Exchange. Мы будем отставать от других сообществ по этому показателю.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky оп-па. А что не так с Яндексом?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov Общий поисковый трафик Яндекса в Рунете почти в два раза больше трафика Google, однако, для любого сайта сети Stack Exchange Яндекс составляет не более 10% от Google ([чуть более развернуто](http://chabanovsky.com/2015/11/yandex-does-not-index-so/)).

Answer (score 11):

Никто (ну, хорошо, *многие люди*) не любит читать хэлпы.

Как у нас говорится -- если ничего не получается, тогда читай инструкцию.

Потому и популярны такие сайты, как наш, что тут можно просто спросить и (может быть) получить ответ.

В идеале, хочется даже не спрашивать на сайте, а набрать какие-то адекватные слова в гугле и увидеть свой, так и не заданный вопрос с уже готовыми ответами.

Тогда напрашивается парадоксальный критерий эффективности, в основе которого лежит **отношение количества просмотров к количеству заданных вопросов** (чем больше, тем база лучше).

К сожалению, сейчас  он не применим, поскольку для того, чтобы он заработал, нужна информация об *успешности просмотров*. Нужно добавить хотя бы что-то вроде простого опроса на странице -- "искал? нашел? тогда поставь галку". (да, я понимаю, что тут могут возникнуть различные проблемы ...)

Но в принципе,  это точно работает. Смотрите, я ни разу не задавал вопросов на `Ask Ubuntu`, но практически всегда находил там нужный `apt get install ...`.

Comment: Я тоже в первую очередь подумал о подобной метрике. (Только в моей версии она еще домножалась на количество вопросов с принятым ответом). Но мне она показалась достаточно бесполезной. Во-первых, непонятна дистанция на которой она достаточно показательна. На короткой она вероятно подъедается сезонными колебаниями, на длинной - динамикой развития ресурса. Во-вторых, это похоже на метрику, на которую можно посматривать иногда, но на основе которой ни в коем случае нельзя принимать решения.

Comment: Но вообще предположения конечно проверить надо, мне лень было)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, мне этот критерий пришел в голову, когда я разделил `day-visits` на `day-questions` для [сайтов тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4160/stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8-stack-exchange-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)

Comment: "искал? нашел? тогда поставь галку" / для этого уже всё есть, просто голосуем за вопрос.

Comment: @alexolut, вы не поняли, это вопрос не для участников сайта, а для любых посетителей.

Comment: Кстати, попробуйте открыть в приватном окне и проголосовать, появится баннер (с дефектами) "Спасибо за отзыв". Вот тут и можно было бы учесть, а может и учитывается даже.

Comment: @alexolut, отличная наводка! Т.е. почти все (в существующем софте)  уже готово?

Comment: @avp для Вашего подхода, получается, что да.

Answer (score 4):

Важным критерием качества базы знаний может быть снижение количества новых дублирующих вопросов. Это должно означать, что посетители самостоятельно находят уже имеющиеся ответы и они их удовлетворяют. Напротив, рост количества дублирующих вопросов будет означать, что пользователи не могут найти уже имеющиеся знания из-за проблем с качеством вопросов/ответов (например они их не понимают), со структурной организацией базы.

Метрика по критерию должна демонстрировать отличие (то есть разность, отношение, доля и прочее) количества вновь заданных дублирующих вопросов за интересующий временной период от такого же количества за другой аналогичный период. Дополнительно можно было бы вычислять ее в разрезе отдельных тем или меток.

Хорошие оценки часто дают "интересным" вопросам и ответам, при этом не обязательно что их практическая ценность высока.

Отношение количества отвеченых/пропущенных вопросов относится скорее к "качеству" сообщества и его компетенции.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, каким образом вы предлагаете вычислять критерии? Было бы здорово, если бы вы предоставили запрос к SEDE!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я с ним не работал и понятия не имею как к нему делать запросы.

Comment: Я бы не назвал этот критерий основным. Во-первых, дубли сами по себе - вещь полезная. Они дают еще один способ найти нужный ответ. Во-вторых, куча дубликатов появляется сезонно (к экзаменам) - но это не означает сезонное же снижение качества.

Comment: Наконец, оптимизация количества дубликатов даст эффект противоположный ожидаемому.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Согласен, исправил. Если учитывать новые то от оптимизации старых лучше не станет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я об этом и написал, то что посетители не могут найти ответы говорит о качестве базы знаний. Студенты очень хороший лакмус, им нужны ответы прямо сейчас и без напрягов. Если они их не находят, то либо пишут дубли либо уходят.

Comment: @Cerbo но наплыв студентов или их пропадание само по себе не означает изменение качества базы знаний, вот в чем дело. То есть надо либо делать поправку на них - либо считать среднегодовое значение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Разумеется следует учитывать сезонность.

Answer (score 3):

Обнаружилась вот такая страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback из состава инструментов модерации. Ссылки на неё сейчас нет в общем перечне инструментов, доступного по адресу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools в разделе "Ссылки". И вроде как было желание страницу вовсе прикрыть. Тем не менее она есть и доступна для участников с >10k репы. Оценки от незарегистрированных участников вполне могут коррелировать с качеством сообщений. Более того, там уже есть соответствующие вкладки: "Наиболее полезные" и "Наименее полезные":

> [image: вкладки]

Подробнее об этом инструменте можно почитать на MSE: [What should we do with anonymous user feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99370/339911)

Answer (score 2):

## Оценка вопросов на основе голосов за и против

> Идея заключается в сравнении общего количества вопросов с количеством вопросов получившими голос против и голос за.

Определим, что такое плохой вопрос. В наиболее общей форме можно говорить, что вопрос плохой, если он имеет отрицательный рейтинг (голосование участников – основной способ разделения плохого содержимого от хорошего).

[image: Статистика голосов за и против]

```
SELECT Mon, COUNT(Mon) AS AllQuestions, SUM(CASE WHEN Score < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DownvotedQuestions, SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UpvotedQuestions
FROM 
(
  SELECT CAST(
      cast(DATEPART(YYYY, CreationDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(MM, CreationDate) as varchar) + '-01'
    as datetime) AS Mon, Score
  FROM Posts
  WHERE PostTypeId = 1
) AS X
GROUP BY Mon
ORDER BY Mon ASC;
```

<sub>Как можно видеть, количество вопросов с отрицательным рейтингом практически не увеличивается. Более того, как видно из графика, количество хороших вопросов (то есть вопросов с рейтингом более нуля) растет с ростом общего количества вопросов, а разрыв количества хороших вопросов к плохим постоянно увеличивается!</sub>

<sub>Скорее всего, можно утверждать, что с ростом популярности сообщества разница между количествов хороших вопросов и плохих будет возрастать.</sub>

Comment: Я бы осторожнее относился к исследованиям на основе подобных картинок. Как минимум, есть еще одна гипотеза, которая такой картинкой не опровергается - *"с ростом сообщества качество вопросов и ответов падает, но оценка через рейтинг не справляется со своей задачей"*.

Comment: Как минимум, надо придумать еще пару проверок, чтобы опровергнуть альтернативную гипотезу.

Comment: `Как можно видеть, количество вопросов с отрицательным рейтингом практически не увеличивается` – из представленной диаграммы этого не видно. Нужен график, показывающий доли двух групп в общем числе вопросов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Этот вопрос именно за тем, чтобы собрать разные взгляды на метрики.

Comment: _"Как можно видеть, количество вопросов с отрицательным рейтингом практически не увеличивается."_ - а это не из-за того, что они удаляются?

Answer (score 1):

- Если решение содержит программный код, то в нём должны быть объяснены все участки, которые составляют суть решения и которые сложнее того уровня подготовки, на котором задан вопрос.

  Например: [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), строка кода `List example = new ArrayList()`. 
  В вопросе новичка про объявление переменных нужно объяснить, почему мы не пишем `ArrayList example = ...`. 
  В вопросе более опытного разработчика про сравнение производительности различных реализаций списков такое объяснение будет излишним.

  Этот критерий довольно часто нарушается в ситуации, когда на вопрос новичка даются сложные ответы, использующие необычные возможности языка, часто написанные в функциональном стиле. Почему-то такие ответы пользуются популярностью и получают высокий рейтинг, вероятно как «остроумные». Однако, если решение не объяснено, то такой ответ — не ответ, а просто хвастовство знаниями.

Comment: "сложные ответы использующие необычные возможности языка" даются обычно на вопросы которые в базе знаний видеть не хочется. Домашки/работа за автора то есть.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка если вопрос слишком большой для обычного ответа, то его надо закрывать и голосовать против, а не ответы давать. Из-за ответов такой вопрос как раз прочно закрепляется в базе данных.

Comment: Ну так иногда ответ ценнее вопроса. Ответы использующие необычные возможности языка часто ценны сами по себе. А вопрос просто дал повод.

Comment: Не соглашусь с требованием объяснения всех участков. Я считаю, что отвечая на вопрос, надо не распыляться по посторонним темам, даже если видно что задавший вопрос - новичек.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка ответы на простые вопросы, использующие необычные возможности языка - полезны только тогда, когда они содержат объяснение происходящему.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не согласен с "только". Иногда достаточно знать что такая штука есть, направление плюс минус 10 градусов, а дальше сам найдешь)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка должно быть хотя бы одно ключевое слово для гугления... Иногда даже его не видно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, давайте переформулируем. Возможно, не все, но по крайней мере те, которые составляют суть решения?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, именно так. Суть решения кроме кода должна быть описана словами, так чтобы читатель понял.

Comment: @PavelMayorov отредактировал, дополняйте. )

Comment: Нам необходимо найти возможность численно оценить качество.

Answer (score 0):

## Оценка на основе остаточного «шума»

Как мы все знаем, задача Stack Overflow минимизировать вредоносный шум, отвлекающий нас от работы во время получения знаний на сайте. Как мне кажется, шумом можно считать все, кроме полезных вопросов и хороших ответов (то есть не удаленных сообщений с неотрицательным рейтингом).

Если упростить оценку и не брать в расчет удаленные сообщения, а также сообщения с низким рейтингом (так как (1) голосование субъективно, (2) ответы с отрицательным рейтингом всегда опускаются в самый низ), спешу предложить метрику на основе остаточного шума: *вопросы и ответы, с не отрицательным рейтингом к не удаленным комментариям*.

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, помимо уже указанных критериев качества важным является такой как **оценка экспертов**. Важно не только то, что показывают формальные просмотры, голоса и удачные поисковые запросы. Важно ещё и то, что эксперт в данной области скажет по данному поводу. Я, конечно, не знаю, как можно "прикрутить" мнение эксперта и в каком соотношении брать силу его голоса, а также как вообще определить уровень самого эксперта, но вопрос был в том, какой критерий можно предложить для определения качества.

К счастью, эксперт нужен не всегда и не во всех случаях. Однако бывают вопросы, оценить целостность и качество ответов на которые может только профессионал высокого класса.

Comment: Из реальных случаев, виденных на ресурсе, я пока видел только ситуации, в которых мнение эксперта было необходимо, чтобы разнести в клочья ответ, предлагающий ерунду с серьёзным лицом, и предположительно поэтому (за серьёзное лицо) получивший парочку плюсов. В таких ситуациях обычно помогает **комментарий** эксперта, а то и его ответ, кроме собственно решения объясняющий проблемы других решений.

Comment: @D-side, сожалею, что всё так плохо. В научном сообществе мнение эксперта (в форме рецензии или публичной оценки, скажем, на защите) является чуть ли не единственным, благодаря которому автор идёт дальше или не идёт никуда (если только не в лженауку). Когда дилетанты начинают оценивать то, в чём слабо разбираются, может получиться ерунда. Так что я хоть и понимаю, что на данном ресурсе такой подход маловероятен, но озвучил недостающий, по моему мнению, критерий. А там уж создатели пусть сами думают, надо это им или нет.

Comment: это наивная точка зрения. Спросите себя почему сайт позволяет несколько ответов публиковать, а не один ответ все редактируют как со статьёй в wikipedia? Почему принятый ответ (с зелёной галочкой) от других участников находится на самом верху сразу под вопросом? Почему автор вопроса (человек почти по определению ответа не знающий) принимает ответ, а не модератор к примеру или скажем участники с золотой меткой, установленной на вопросе? (которые вероятно больше опыта имеют по теме). Научное сообщество: знакомы ли вы с оценкой процента статей, которые не удалось воспроизвести в вашей области?

Comment: Начинать нужно с фактов: выберите любую тему, которую вы хорошо понимаете: посмотрите на популярные и не очень ответы в этой теме. Проголосуйте «за» полезные с вашей точки зрения "эксперта" ответы. Оставьте комментарии, голосуйте «против» вредных ответов, добавьте свой ответ. После сотен-тысяч ответов вы убедитесь, что в среднем ваше  мнение совпадает с мнением большинства (популярный ответ как правило полезен—на вопрос отвечает, даже если он не самый лучший по каким-то критериям).

Comment: Подскажите, зачем необходимо мнение _одного_ эксперта? Важно ли оно? Даст ли оно какую–либо оценку и что с ней можно будет делать? Более того, чем механизм голосования отличается от предложенного решения? Основная задача сайта – создать базу знаний. Вопрос должен быть полезен людям, а не формальному эксперту. Критерии качества, на мой взгляд, должны дать критическую оценку тому, на сколько создаваемые знания полезны сообществу. Сегодня такими критериями могут считаться: 1) количество просмотров вопроса; 2) голоса в вопросе; 3) от части, количество обратных ссылок.

Answer (score -2):

Я начал учится тогда, когда понял что нужно учится учится. Невозможно помочь пришедшему сюда в половину силы, ибо это не помощь, а самоутверждение. Знаю по себе, что иногда важнее получить каплю самоутверждения нежели дать полноценный ответ. Но из этого следует что просто выписать пришедшему рецепт будет недостаточно, ему нужно ещё и знания в голову вложить. Возможно есть языки в которых хелпы уже по десять лет не меняются и создают эффект прупика, но есть языки в которых обновление чуть ли не каждый день и качество перевода или пояснений желает лучшего. Вот как в таких ситуациях быть? Я написал код, который является рецептом, но каждый раз пересказывать слова которые должны быть константными и находится в хелпах, лично мне надоедает. Да, можно идти и править хелпы, но тогда зачем SO? Давайте из хелпов сделаем SO. Или же давайте на SO сделаем особый хелп, который будет постоянно форматироваться и дополнятся, а ссылки на конкретные объяснения сделают помощь нуждающимся ещё интереснее и эффективнее.

Других вариантов нет.

И ещё хочу вложить в голову создателей идею эволюции SO под пользователей. Пользователи постоянно вырастают и отваливаются из-за того, что им здесь становится скучно. Если раньше все дети сидели в песочницах для конкретного языка, а подобные ресурсы были для более продвинутых специалистов, которые давая более качественные ответы заманили детей сюда и эти самые дети вытеснили всех предшественников. Вам нужно подумать, как повышать интерес для тех, кто уже вырос из уровня хелпов.

Сейчас очень круто говорить о архитектуре, парадигмах и прочем, что нельзя сделать не на одном мне известном ресурсе в полную меру. Для этого нужно создавать множество нового чего ещё нигде нет, но когда появится, лично я не задумываясь уйду туда, чтобы не просто отвечать, но ещё и получать знания.

Comment: *"Или же давайте на SO сделаем особый хелп, который будет постоянно форматироваться и дополнятся, а ссылки на конкретные объяснения сделают помощь нуждающимся ещё интереснее и эффективнее."* [Возможно, вы удивитесь, но...](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Comment: @D-side и там можно писать на русском?

Comment: Нельзя, в тематике StackOverflow строго английский язык. Но факт, они этим занимаются, когда пройдут стадию беты, будут шансы и у других сообществ, например у нашего.

Comment: @D-side, жаль.. Я просто почему думал что нет такой возможности, так как помню тему в которой подобный вопрос поднимался и совет по созданию хелпа был жестко раскритикован.. я ещё тогда читал и думал что жаль что с автором совета не согласны,  а то было бы здорово.

Comment: Было бы прикольно если бы скоро и о удержании опытного контингента, который только и в состоянии притянуть других, задумаются :)

Comment: Когда этот раздел запустили, там начало твориться светопредставление. Репутация на какое-то время обесценилась за счёт публикации простых но ходовых примеров (и за *каждый* плюс *каждому* соавтору начислялось по 5 репы), в правках царил разброд и хаос из-за рецензирования новичками, в чатах сыпались "review pls [ссылка]", примеры летали между топиками, множась и исчезая... В общем, адъ :)

Comment: ...не знаю, что там творится сейчас, но такая ситуация оттолкнула от раздела многих знающих людей. Хотя я допускаю, что осталось тоже немало. Всё-таки написание авторских ответов и разработка/доработка канонической документации по теме это существенно разные рода деятельности, и аудитория, по вполне понятным причинам, отличается. Но как решили проблему рецензирования новичками, я так в итоге и не узнал. Убежал оттуда со всех ног :)

Comment: @D-side беда может быть только тогда, когда новички будут проверять работу новичков... А не новичкам врят ли будет интересно проверять. Хотя это и может быть причиной по которой не новички как раз таки и не уйдут. Вместо надоедливых однотипных вопросов, они могут в закрытых комнатах совместно работать над хелпами. То есть обсуждать темы уровня хелпа где хоть и примитивная информация, но умение её подать и является мастерством. И пусть кто-то напишет и не сможет пройти, но зато он сможет узнать причину по которой не прошел и подтянув знания придти и попробовать исправить.

Comment: Не любят люди читать хэлпы

Comment: @avp ну ведь это абсурд. Как это программист и не любит читать хелпы? Возможно не все хелпы.. Есть просто документация, которую читать реально скучно, но именно поэтому и круто самому её создавать. Ведь стоит только одному написать в правильном ключе, как все остальные будут равняться на него. Мне кажется с этим проблем не должно быть.

Answer (score -7):

Насколько я знаю, из старой литературы, база знаний это не только набор структурированной информации, а и некоторая логическая вычислительная система позволяющая не только отвечать на вопросы и делать логические выводы, но предоставлять их ход. В данном случае речь идет о банке данных. В истории известна база знаний по кардиологии (уже не помню как называлась) которая диагностировала лучше чем каждый из, более чем тыячи, отдельно взятых кардиологов, знания которых были сосредоточены в системе.

Comment: Э... о чем вы?..

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Об этом https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_base

Comment: А зачем?........

Comment: Это совершенно не отвечает на заданный вопрос и должно быть скорее комментарием.

Comment: @D-side Качество любой системы есть вещь чисто субъективная и оно, качество, может быть оценено только в процессе эксплуатации этой системы самим потребителем. Если вы не поняли сказанного.

Comment: @Вячеслав в "ответе" это не написано. В "ответе" исключительно указание на неверное употребление термина и потому неверную постановку вопроса. Конкретных предложений в нём нет.

Comment: @Вячеслав «_Качество любой системы есть вещь чисто субъективная и оно, качество, может быть оценено только в процессе эксплуатации этой системы самим потребителем_» – пожалуйста, раскройте эту мысль в вашем ответе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я хотел сказать, что какими бы замечательными техническими характерисиками не обладала система, если она не удовлетворяет функциональным потребностям потребителя, то о каком качестве можно говорить. Прочность, надежность, долговечность, и даже удобство использования, как правило, уступают на рынке красоте, моде, и цене. Увы.