# Где найти практику?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Всем привет! Я знаю, что очень много информации по поводу практики. Ответов большинство на сайте "создай свой проект" и т.д. Но по факту, как можно создать свой проект, когда начинающий только в среде .net? Где можно нормальную практику наработать. Просто одно дело учить синтаксис, другое дело его реально использовать в задачах. Это как иностранный язык. Одно дело знать, зубрить... Другое дело действительно говорить, читать и т.д. Вот вы где свою практику нашли?

Comment: Ну если вы не можете придумать какую бы вам программу написать, поищите примеры на ютубе: [вот пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6RNy3rPZpg&index=8&list=PLWCoo5SF-qAMDIAqikhB2hvIytrMiR5TC) написания простейшего приложения, или [вот еще](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k91jTTdr0GM), ну и действуйте как в армии "смотри и повторяй за мной", "если не доходит через голову, дойдет через руки". Таким образом можно понаделать несколько программулин. А далее уже надо самому себе придумать и поставить задачу и реализовать ее.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Чтобы практика была полезна, решайте задачи, которые находятся на границе ваших сегодняшних способностей и получайте отклик о результате, чтобы дурных привычек не накапливать (именно поэтому рекомендуют учить именно тот язык, который знакомый вам программист хорошо знает). Это метод: deliberate practice + feedback.

Для совсем начинающих есть [тысячи простых проектов](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2a9ygh/1000_beginner_programming_projects_xpost/).

Если вы уверены что ваш код рабочий и готовы услышать о нём любые отклики, то попробуйте опубликовать код в метке [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info) или на http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Посмотрите [на существующие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50), чтобы знать что ожидать.

Помимо этого, попробуйте патчи посылать с исправлением бага, реализацией новой функциональности в понравившийся вам open-source проект. Как минимум, чтобы получить навык изменения не крошечного кода и работы с другими людьми. Даже в больших, старых проектах есть простые задачи, которые по силам начинающим. Посмотрите в CONTRIBUTING.md или аналоге (если есть) указания для начинающих. Некоторые проекты специально отмечают простые issues или даже специальные менторские программы имеют. Не бойтесь спрашивать конкретных указаний как вы можете помочь проекту (в списке рассылке или другом методе общения участников, выбранного вами проекта).

Comment: @OlmerDale что это в переводе на человеческий язык означает?  Вы утверждаете что практиковаться, участвуя в open-source невозможно (ложь)/неэффективно (по сравнению с чем и кому — напишите свой ответ, если есть лучше по вашему варианты) или что другое?

Comment: Если перевести мои слова на "человеческий из мира холоворд", то это звучит примерно так - "нефиг соваться в опенсорс, если мозгов не хватает даже на первый проект, который хочется написать после прочтения первой книжки". Но это более грубо чем посоветовать стать президентом планеты. Но судя по тому насколько шаблонно Вы пытаетесь дать ответ, то Вам вообще пофигу до автора темы, ведь хочется заработать побольше плюсиков за обобщенный ответ. Пусть и вправду виндовс пишет, а то индусам сложно. И свой ответ я давать не хочу тут и без меня назвали много способов решения проблемы.

Comment: @OlmerDale ответ *явно* говорит о "границе способностей"  Ответ призван помочь как автору так и другим людям. Автор принял ответ, значит тоже что-то полезное для себя увидел.  А то что ответ написан так чтобы не только автору пригодился -- это миссия Stack Overflow. Посмотрите [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Comment: Если ребенок спросит на чем ему добираться до детского сада, а ему ответят на мотоцикле, то его тоже такой ответ устроит и он с радостью его выберет! И плюсуют видимо те, кто вообще не понимает о чем речь. В вопросе явно упомянуто что человек только встал на путь программирования, какой ему опенсорс? Если бы Вы создали библиотеку или фраймворк, Вы бы хотели чтобы Вам пулреквесты делал тот кто сегодня только книгу читать закончил? Вы из какого мира?

Comment: @OlmerDale: если вы пытаетесь сказать, что человек с вопросом "Где найти практику?" не способен в принципе пользу получить от написания патча для open-source проекта, что смешно даже говорить об этом, что это равнозначно этому человеку стать "президентом планеты", то тогда это конечно **неверно**. У нас нет ни одного "президента планеты", поэтому даже один пример противного будет достаточен — этим примером могу быть я —подобный вопрос у меня не раз возникал, просто так я код не читаю, успешная попытка исправления бага/реализация фичи проверяет, что я себе не обманываю, что понимаю прочитанное.

Comment: Я хочу сказать что читать нужно не только заголовки, но ещё и было бы здорово помогать тем кто эти вопросы задает, а не вступать в трение с неокрепшими умами советуя лезть в опенсорс.

Comment: @OlmerDale пока я от вас вижу только громкие заявления с тонной апломба и высокомерия. Обосновать как-то можете или это всё пустой трёп?

Answer (score 8):

Ну раз перетащили на мету, тогда отвечу.

Сначала писал примитивные игрушки, текстовые и не очень, для себя любимого. Собственно сам процесс писания и был игрушкой. Потом, в какой-то момент появилась задача обработать кучу данных, поискал как можно автоматизировать, нашел .NET, попробовал, 2 дня писал скрипт, потом за 15 минут выполнил работу, на которую руками ушла бы неделя, понравилось. А дальше уже целенаправленно пытался автоматизировать все что считал возможным. Именно считал возможным, понимание о невозможности или нецелесообразности некоторых вещей приходило потом, в процессе. Попутно читал все что попадалось интересного на связанные темы, пробовал прочитанное в текущих "проектах" или просто писал скрипт, проектом или программой это называть слишком, без конкретной цели, просто чтобы попробовать новую для меня фичу.

Так что все зависит от вашего личного желания. Настоящего желания, а не простого следования моде, мейнстриму или "потому что друг Вася программист", называйте как хотите.

PS: Кладбище костылей и велосипедов бережно хранится в архивах бекапов.

Answer (score 2):

Простые задачи можно научиться самостоятельно решать, хорошо знать язык и стандартную библиотеку, научиться с базами взаимодействовать на ADO.NET (без ORM, чтобы понимать всю эту кухню). Пожалуй, это самые универсальные вещи, которые понадобятся для 90% вакансий. А потом можно работу искать, это будет своего рода ускорение.

Свой проект - это бестолково, ибо без умения в архитектуру это будет кладбище костылей и привычки, которые будут трудно выводиться потом.

В общем, хорошо бы научиться читать чужой код. Поищите что-нибудь интересное на гитхабе, постарайтесь понять, что там и к чему, какие подсистемы и как взаимодействуют. Когда это перестанет вызывать страдания, вы уже станете ценным кадром.

Comment: а откуда возьмется умение в архитектуру, если не тыкаться носом в собственные архитектурные ошибки? Чужой опыт и ошибки так и останутся чужими. Так что свой проект и кладбище костылей просто необходимы. по поводу вредных привычек, их и на работе набраться можно.

Comment: на гитхабе полно кода, на который без слёз не взглянешь. Не зная, как нормальный код должен выглядеть, также можно дурных привычек набрать.

Comment: @jfs Именно благодаря этому человек заметит разницу между тем, что читается легко, а что читать невозможно. За собой такое заметить нельзя потому, что алгоритм очевиден писателю.

Comment: @rdorn Собственные очевидные архитектурные ошибки демотивируют ("Ох, блин, опять все переделывать!"), а неочевидные становятся трудноискоренимыми привычками.

Comment: @free_ze позволю себе не согласиться, все люди разные, все очень индивидуально, впрочем, переубеждать вас тоже не стану, каждый имеет право на собственное мнение.

Answer (score 1):

Решение прикладных задач, как правило поручают опытным разработчикам. Но я свою практику ищу сам - анализирую, составляю ТЗ. Пока коммерческого использования конечно нет