# Прекратить [диалоги-о-работе] на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, удаление-метки, диалоги-о-работе

Выросло из [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5799/%D0%94%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#comment22146_5804), который на данный момент поддержало аж 10 человек (учитывая то, сколько всего людей тут читает комментарии, это немало):

> [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) тоже надо удалить :D – [D-side](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5799/%D0%94%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#comment22146_5804)

Может, пора бы уже принимать меры? Эксперимент определённо провалился:

- Сообщество изъявляет обоснованное недовольство существованием этой метки ([1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=38939267#38939267), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=38723962#38723962), [3 (касательно)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38929147#38929147)), и в опросе о судьбе таких вопросов лидирует вариант ["в топку их"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4595/181100).
- <s>У метки **до сих пор нет описания**, а значит и однозначно определённой тематики. Это проблема, из-за которой участники трактуют значение метки как хотят.</s> **UPD:** [добавили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5/info). Правда, [в нынешнем виде](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6596/1) оно совершенно не работает против "трактуют как хотят", и уничтожает понятие "онтопик для Меты".
- Де-факто метка притягивает **явный оффтопик** (удалённые, видны только 10к+: [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5595/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5757/181100), [3](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5481/181100)) и используется для переноса оффтопика с основного сайта ([1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4980/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/conversation/regarding-burnination-of---), [3](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5804/181100)), хотя здесь это не меньший оффтопик: [Мета для вопросов **о сообществе Stack Overflow на русском**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Сохраняя эту метку, мы поощряем оффтопик и снижаем соотношение сигнал/шум.

Предлагаю (последовательно):

1. Пересмотреть все заданные по метке вопросы и принять решение: **удалить** или поставить **историческую блокировку**, чтобы дать понять, что вопросы из этой области здесь больше не приветствуются. С того, что на Мете уместно (в т. ч. с этого вопроса), просто снять метку и тем самым исключить из рассмотрения. Как структурировать пересмотр, предлагаю обсудить в комментариях (и отредактировать вопрос, когда к чему-нибудь придём):

   - Создать о каждом вопросе общий ответ, в котором изложить доводы, обсуждая их в комментариях и в чате. Спустя заданное время (неделя после публикации?), принять меры.
   - Дать время на закрытие всего, что не представляет ценности (и переоткрытие всего, что представляет), и закрытое удалить. Остальное заблокировать, как исторически важное.
2. Уничтожить метку [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) и прекратить перенос на Мету явного оффтопика.

---

Если вы против уничтожения этой метки, поставьте вопросу минус и изложите ваши доводы в форме ответа. Если по итогам будет принято решение "оставить метку", нужно будет рассмотреть вопросы её употребления: определить нормы, добавить описание и изменить [соответствующую страницу справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), т. к. получается, что там не вполне правда.

Comment: Вижу [tag:диалоги-о-работе] – ставлю минус почти всегда.

Comment: По сути: сайт — для вопросов о программировании. Мета — для вопросов о сайте. А чтобы поболтать есть чат.

Comment: От части этот вопрос уже обсуждался ранее: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4589/ Вероятно, прочтение предыдущий дискуссии поможет принять правильное решение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin поболтать - да. Но, как я понимаю, в некоторых случаях хочется видеть отдельные тематические долгоживущие страницы, а не размазанность по чату, которую новый участник не найдет никогда, а старый уже через пару дней.

Comment: А почему бы не создать официальный чат для диалогов о работе? Можно даже специально переоткрывать его, если никто не пишет.

Comment: @VladD [флудильня](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23460/ru-so) сгодится :) Напоминаю, что мы до сих пор не определили тематику метки. Поэтому более подходящий чат подобрать не представляется возможным.

Comment: @D-side В вопросе, кстати, никак не освещены проблемы, которые были рассмотрены в исходной публикации, представляющей эту метку. Любой ответ в поддержку будет в значительной мере повторять данную публикацию: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4589/ Было бы здорово услышать ваши идеи и предложения о том, как мы будем решать указанные проблемы без этой метки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky заметьте, я в вопросе ссылаюсь на эту публикацию с самого начала. Вот только ответы: отказ от таких вопросов, признание проблемы, признание проблемы, неполное решение (слабо поддержанное) и единственное конкретное решение (встретившее яростное сопротивление). Но то решение, что используется сейчас, не было предложено вовсе, а при этом наносит Мете вред, о чём у меня в вопросе и сказано. Нужно другое решение. А рассматриваемая проблема не требует "отсутствия простоя", какое-то время можно пожить и без решения вовсе.

Comment: @D-side Я именно в этом и вижу проблему. Я могу опубликовать тот вопрос ответом в этом. Вероятно, его поддержат ровно те же люди. В этом случае, мы придем к тому же, с чего начали. Чтобы этого избежать, как мне кажется, было бы здорово рассмотреть указанные в исходном вопросе проблемы. Сейчас мы имеем «давайте уберем, оно мне мешает», но идея в том, что данная метка решает вполне конкретную проблему, которую, видимо, вы не разделяете (и в этом нет ничего плохого). Подскажите, пожалуйста, если мы удалим метку, каким образом будут решены указанные в исходном вопросе проблемы?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky кажется, редактируя комментарий, я случайно ответил на ваш ответ. Но коротко: проблем**а** (а в вопросе поднята всего одна) решена не будет, а мы будем искать новое решение (если сообщество решит уничтожить метку) или доводить до ума существующее (если нет).

Comment: @VladD , в area51 мб напишем?)

Comment: @br3t: О, а это идея :)

Comment: @br3t к сожалению, SO до сегодняшнего дня отклоняли все предложения о новых русскоязычных сообществах с чем-то вроде "у нас на данный момент нет на это ресурсов". Но направление интересное :)

Comment: Вон даже у _augur_ есть свой сайт в сети. Главное - правильно назвать то, чем мы там ~не~ будем заниматься.

Comment: @D-side Вероятно, стоит сначала попробовать найти решение, а потом отменять существующее.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky необязательно. Если от решения больше вреда, чем пользы, отменить его лучше, чем не отменять. Независимо от того, есть ли этому решению замена.

Comment: Кто нибудь киньте ссылку, где написано, что нельзя в SO обсуждать работу

Comment: @Barmaley в этом вопросе обсуждается неуместность вопросов о работе **на Мете**. То, что на ней нельзя обсуждать работу, следует [из соответствующей страницы в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). На основном сайте же почти всё с меткой [tag:работа] позакрывали, и [сожжение соответствующей метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5799/%D0%94%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) скорее формальное признание того, что уже сложилось.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky отвечаю на [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5812/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5#comment22236_5812). Мы вообще не обязаны решать эти проблемы, с меткой или без. Людям хочется поныть, как они страдают, что вынуждены работать и учиться. Те же самые вопросы можно задать о работе пожарника, библиотекаря или юриста. Пускай обсуждают где хотят, но не здесь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вероятно, проблема в отсутствие четких правил, а не в самой метке. Нытье нытьем, но метка была добавлена совершенно по другим причинам (возьмите хотя бы [вопрос про работу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/)).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky четкие правила есть: сайт — для вопросов о программировании, Мета — для вопросов о сайте, чат — для обсуждения работы, учебы, личной жизни и чего угодно ещё.

Answer (score 7):

Очевидно, что вопросы с этой меткой интересны.
Вот рейтинги: +36, +19, +15, +15, +10, +6 (закрыт), +6, +6, +4.

Любое удаление должно быть индивидуальным. Не надо лишать возможности задавать интересные вопросы, а тем более, не надо удалять вопросы, которые были интересны.

А некоторые из вопросов о работе с основного сайта уже обсуждались ранее и на них вешалась историческая блокировка.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Заплюсованность сообщения ещё не значит, что оно уместно в формате SO.

Comment: @alexolut, надо формат подгонять под сообщения, а не сообщения под формат.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а зачем тогда формат, если его каждый раз подо все подгонять???

Comment: Так не пойдёт. Вся сеть Stack Exchange задумывалась для минимизации всякого шлака. Если не опираться на какой-то базовый принцип всё пойдёт крахом.

Comment: `некоторые из вопросов о работе с основного сайта уже обсуждались ранее и на них вешалась историческая блокировка.` - нужно не знающим людям пояснить, что историческая блокировка не значит, что вопрос на столько эпичен и супер крут, что имеет право на существование, а то, что это было раньше в давно минувших днях, когда этот ресурс еще не был ruSO и это было так сказать средне приемлемо и было жалко шлак удалять. кстати историк лок был лишь у пары вопросов. остальное просто не по теме было закрыто

Comment: Кстати, первые два вопроса из предоставленного списка вполне приемлемы для Меты, т.к. затрагивают SO. Остальные - нет!

Comment: Если молоток не подходит для закручивания шурупов это не означает, что нужно подгонять молоток под шурупы.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот когда у нас будет на русском столько же сайтов, сколько на английском, и под каждый вопрос можно будет найти сайт, тогда и надо будет говорить о том, что он не вписывается в тематику. А пока это просто русскоязычное сообщество программистов и в тематику не вписывается всякая биология, химия и т. д. А работа - вполне вписывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy я тебе и на биологию и химию спокойно напридумываю вопросы, которые будут тесно связаны.. чего это ты их сразу отсеял? Нет уж, извольте.  Вот когда у нас будет на русском столько же сайтов, сколько на английском, и под каждый вопрос можно будет найти сайт, тогда и надо будет говорить о том, что они не вписываются в тематику...))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну так я не против. Но у нас сообщество программистов. На вопросы по биологии программисты обычно ответить не могут, поэтому это оффтопик. На вопросы о работе, администрировании программах - могут.

Comment: @Qwertiy это неправильная логика и не так работает. То, что кто-то не может на что-то ответить не является поводом объявить это оффтопиком. То, что кто-то имел опыт написания кода фаллосом и может поделиться - не делает тему онтопичной)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если хотя бы 30% имели такой опыт, то делает :)

Comment: @D-side, отчего же не подходит? :) Метку - сжечь, но по ней бывают интересные вопросы.

Comment: @Aid стоит заметить, что вопрос может быть интересен и даже онтопичен и без этой метки.

Comment: @alexolut, Я об этом и сказал: метку выжечь, вопрос, **возможно**, оставить.

Comment: @Aid прочитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос ещё разок. Я именно это и предлагаю.

Comment: @D-side, разговор двух алкоголиков про одно и то же уважение. Вы это предлагаете, я предлагаю, в чём проблема? :)

Comment: @Aid значит, я совершенно не понял, что имелось в виду в вашем первом комментарии здесь.

Answer (score 3):

Из чата по [просьбе](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39763216#39763216):

> Мне кажется, что [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) на SO (мету) это попытка впихнуть на SO то, что должно быть на форумах. Надо просто признать, что нельзя тащить на SO всё, к чему неравнодушно сообщество. Надо придерживаться множества разрешённых тем и продолжать закрывать нетематические вопросы, даже если они собирают большое кол-во плюсов (как это делается на основном сайте). SO - о программировании (с учётом правил), metaSO - о сайте SO. Точка!

Comment: На хэшкоде почему-то были уместны, а теперь вдруг стали нет? Если вопрос интересен, он должен остаться.

Comment: @Qwertiy, таким мы сейчас не на хэшкоде ;-)

Comment: @Grundy видимо Qwertiy продолжает заходить сюда через [hashcode.ru](http://hashcode.ru)

Comment: Кстати, тонкий намёк. Вот я люблю [meta-tag:велосипеды] и чай [meta-tag:пуэр].

Comment: @NickVolynkin ничего не понял, но кажется, я об этом уже как-то слышал :)

Comment: @alexolut ну как же, надо сделать их онтопиком и обсуждать на Мете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin nope

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно рассматривать данной предложение в отрыве от [исходной публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4589/6) о введении данной метки. По большому счету, данный вопрос должен бы быть опубликован ответом в исходном вопросе.

#### Метку с Меты удалять не стоит, как и опубликованные вопросы по ней

Не вижу возможности удалить данную метку пока не будет другого более верного / оптимального решения указанной в исходном вопросе проблемы. Вносить изменения стоит лишь в том случае, если новое решение (1) решает проблему, решенную предыдущим решением, (2) решает ее эффективнее, как минимум на столько, что бы мы стали тратить усилия по внедрению нового решения.

С другой стороны, крайне поддерживаю добавление описания метки и приведение заданных вопросов по ней к обговоренной структуре.

Comment: Вносить изменения стоит ещё и в том случае, если это решает больше проблем, чем поднимает.

Comment: @D-side В данном вопросе не указаны создаваемые проблемы данным решением, как и в исходном. Пожалуйста, приведите их!

Comment: Они указаны маркированным списком прямо в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @D-side 3 участника – не есть все сообщество. Инициативу поддержало как минимум +20, не говоря об ответах. Соглашусь, что описание следует добавить, но с удалением метки и _всех_ вопросов по ней, к сожалению – нет.

Comment: @D-side К слову, согласен, что часть уже заданных вопросов на Мете стоит либо удалить, либо как–то переформулировать. [meta-tag:нытьё] != [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе].

Comment: Вы, кажется, не прочитали вопрос вообще (и я сейчас не обвиняю, а скорее призываю прочитать внимательнее). Каким-то образом вы пропустили прямо изложенные в вопросе проблемы, и упустили тот факт, что я **не предлагаю удалить все вопросы по метке**, а предлагаю пересмотреть их (в результате чего **или** удалить их, **или** заблокировать). А +20 не у инициативы, а у постановки проблемы. А об ответах к этому вопросу мы уже ранее говорили.

Comment: @D-side Из третьего пункта по–умолчанию следует удаление всех вопросов по этой метке.

Comment: Не вполне понял, какой пункт понимается под "третьим": третьего нумерованного нет, а из третьей проблемы это не следует. В вопросе прямым текстом предлагается в первом пункте: "Пересмотреть все заданные по метке вопросы и принять решение: удалить или поставить историческую блокировку". И варианты того, как это организовать. Об этом, кстати, вообще никакой обратной связи не поступило :) Как минимум один голос (знаю чей, но личности мы не обсуждаем) против инициативы был отдан явно с мыслью "А, он хочет удалить все [диалоги-о-работе], не бывать этому!", но я этого и не предлагаю.

Comment: @D-side _Де-факто метка притягивает явный оффтопик _ – нетематические вопросы запрещены. Метка делает их допустимыми. Без метки их всех следует удалить. Кроме того, исторической ценности они не несут и споров не вызывают, по большей массе.

Comment: Это уже ваши личные домыслы. На большом StackOverflow осталось немало вопросов, ставших нетематическими, но оставшихся на сайте под исторической блокировкой. А историческую ценность рассматриваемые нами вопросы имеют уже потому, что несмотря на их оффтопичность их почему-то перенесли на Мету, а не уничтожили на месте, и сообщество приложило существенные усилия в попытках на них ответить. То, что они не вызывают споров, нормально. Споры у таких вопросов бывают, но не всегда. Те, что есть, пресекать, разумеется, необходимо.

Comment: @D-side Большенство вопросов были заданы уже после создания метки – поэтому их и перенесли, иначе бы просто удалили. Я говорю про ненужность исторической блокировки на Мете, не на основном сайте.

Comment: Перенос их обратно на основной сайт и историческую блокировку там я не рассматривал, но это тоже решение. Хотя чем оно выгодно по сравнению с исторической блокировкой тут, на Мете, я не улавливаю.

Comment: Если вы к тому, что нетематических вопросов нет на meta.SO, а есть только на SO -- так это потому, что они не совершали той ошибки, которую мы совершили здесь. Или совершали, но уже все давно об этом забыли.

Comment: @D-side Так нет опции переноса их обратно и исторической блокировки. Историческую блокировку мы используем для вопросов, которые ранее были разрешены, но стали вне тематики сайта по прошествию времени. Обсуждаемые вопросы никогда не были в этих условиях.

Comment: А как же объявление метки [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе]? Чем не объявление тематичности?

Comment: @D-side Данная инициатива существует исключительно в рамках Меты. Причем это действительно инициатива – мы смотрим, как оно идет. В объявлении явно сказано, что таким вопросам нет и не будет (как минимум, в обозримом будущем) места на основном сайте.

Comment: А я говорю о тематичности на Мете. В вопросе в том числе.