# Где задавать дискуссионные вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

У меня есть вопрос по типу "Что выбрать в такой-то ситуации?".

На SO такой задавать нельзя, т.к. он не имеет однозначного ответа.

Но мне всё же хотелось бы узнать мнение сообщества по этому поводу в виде:

- позиция/вариант
- объективная причина почему именно так

Может такие вопросы можно задавать на Мете?

Comment: Пример такого вопроса приведите)

Comment: @Suvitruf например "Какой язык/платформу выгоднее учить среди Язык1 и Язык2 при поиске первой работы, при условии, что устроит любой из них?". Это кратко (без подробностей), чтобы не делать из комментария полотно.

Comment: Вопрос поиска работа в принципе лежит вне плоскости обсуждений SO. Ну, это если не брать в расчёт, что "выгоднее" - весьма расплывчатое понятие.

Comment: @Suvitruf, так вопрос в пределах области IT, то есть актуален для сообщества, но, согласен, не для SO. Потому и интересуюсь можно ли такое задать на мете. Суть в том, что мне просто хотелось бы оказаться на столько интересным кандидатом на стажировку (причём оплачиваемую), на сколько возможно в пределах моих интересов. И советы сообщества бы оказались полезны. НО засорять неуместными вопросами площадку тоже не хотелось. А на Мете я вижу вопросы довольно разных направленностей, вот и решил, что тут выбор темы, возможно, более свободный.

Comment: Мета посвящена обсуждению самого SO, так что можете попробовать задать вопрос в чате.

Comment: @Arhad не подскажите как можно найти подходящий чат или может порекомендуете конкретный?

Comment: Можете попробовать спросить в [основном чате Ru.SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462). А вообще, список всех комнат доступен на https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Arhad спасибо за разъяснение и совет.

Comment: @Mr.Modest вы сформулировал стандартный вопрос "C# или Java". Это дико офтопичный вопрос. Ничем хорошим обсуждение таких вопросов не заканчивается :)

Comment: @PashaPash, так а что делать если именно такой вопрос и возникает? Тут услышал про ASP.Net Core, а там услышал про Spring MVC и не знаешь что лучше учить :(

Comment: @Mr.Modest учите C# и ASP.Net Core.

Comment: @PashaPash и его джуниорского знания (а больше я его вряд ли освою до лета) будет достаточно для поиска стажировки с нулевым опытом? =/

Comment: @Mr.Modest знания любого фреймворка на джуниорском урове вам будет достаточно для поиска стажировки. выбирайте то, что лично вам нравится - хоть nodejs (вариант даже лучше чем asp.net). только PHP не учите. и Java тоже не рассматривайте (если хотите в веб уйти)

Comment: @Mr.Modest а вообще - приходите в чат, там насоветуют

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На все вопросы, близкие к тематике сайта, но выходящие за рамки идеологии SO (четкий вопрос — однозначный ответ), в которых предполагается дискуссия, вы можете (попробовать) получить ответы в любом из подходящих по тематике вопроса [чатов](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com).

Попытки расширить тематику вопросов на Мете обычно [не очень хорошо воспринимаются сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/176217).