# Почему сообщество ruSO на Meta не поддерживает осуждённых разработчиков?

Tags: обсуждение

Почему на Мете не говорят о программистах (разработчиках), которых осудили (например, за мирный пикет) и никак не информируют сообщество? Складывается такое ощущение, что нет никакого сообщества, что есть только бизнес и каждый сам за себя.

Для примера - "**Дело сети**". За ребят заступается всё больше и больше человек из разных профессий, но только не из сообщества разработчиков.

Comment: Сначала они пришли за социалистами, и я молчал — потому что я не был социалистом.
Затем они пришли за членами профсоюза, и я молчал — потому что я не был членом профсоюза.
Затем они пришли за евреями, и я молчал — потому что я не был евреем.
Затем они пришли за мной — и не осталось никого, чтобы говорить за меня.

Comment: Потому что Stack Overflow и его Мета предназначены не для этого.

Comment: С другой стороны, я бы не отказался от места, в котором можно было бы поболтать с тутошним сообществом на свободные темы, в том числе на эту. Наверное, таким местом мог бы быть чат, но там оффтопик вроде тоже когда-то не особо жаловали (да и чаты как-то слишком заныканы от остального сайта)

Comment: @andreymal раньше было [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе], пока не [закопали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/15479).

Comment: @andreymal можно создать своё ;)

Comment: @edem после моего нытья про лицензии мне пора свой собственный аналог всего Stack Overflow создавать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (но так как он всё равно не взлетит, я ничего не делаю)

Comment: @andreymal сомневаюсь, что это можно узнать наперёд)

Comment: @andreymal, [политота](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so)?

Comment: Пока больше дизов и это очень удручает.  Понаблюдаю..

Comment: @edem оно от части уже есть, см. в моем профиле альтернативный чатт

Comment: @andreymal создайте группу в телеге =)

Comment: Это зависит от людей, составляющих сообщество и руководство сайта. Стоит им захотеть — и ресурс будет выполнять социальные функции. SO на русском достаточно значимый сайт, чтобы, например, его заявления публиковали СМИ. Но, видимо, не хотят: за все годы существования ресурса я не видел примеров его участия в общественной жизни. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных спасибо. Дельный комментарий.

Comment: труд работников «it» (в сравнении с большинством других работников) оплачивается довольно высоко. утратить такие привилегии — страшновато. а своя рубашка, как известно, ближе к телу. оттого и легче закрывать глаза на недостатки диктатутры буржуазии. коротко: неподходящая здесь аудитория для демонстрации возмущения.

Comment: @doox911, как вы представляете действенную поддержку с нашей стороны? Написать письмо президенту?

Comment: @СашаЧерных очень хороший вопрос.

Comment: @alexandr barakin, пример из недавнего прошлого. Российские знаменитости — отнюдь не бедствующая категория населения — [**массово выступили**](https://www.bbc.com/russian/features-49724982) против приговора Павлу Устинову.

Comment: Причём, возможно, они рисковали даже больше. я ну совсем не утверждаю, что высококлассным IT-шникам за границей будет легко. Однако если власть пожелает вставлять палки в колёса актёрам — например, по-тихому распорядится, чтобы им не давали роли, не пускали на ТВ, — и перед теми встанет вопрос о выезде за рубеж, то найти сопоставимую работу там известным в пределах одной страны людям будет очень проблематично. Спасибо.

Comment: @doox911, мне не понравился вопрос. Ср. с «[**Реальные действия — это тренировки на полигоне?**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35104334#35104334)» от того же пользователя. По структуре эти сообщения напоминают [**описанный Поварниным**](https://evolkov.net/critic.think/povarnin/povarnin.23.html) приём: «По многим вопросам возможно, мыслимо не одно, не два, а несколько, много решений, несколько предположений и т. д. (…) Но из мыслимых решений вопроса он (…) выбирает нелепое. Чем ярче контраст (…), тем лучше. Все остальные возможные решения замалчиваются.»

Comment: Если отвечать по существу того вопроса, то лучшим решением, по моему мнению, было бы создание темы на Мете, где обсуждались бы возможные (разумеется, законные) методы на случай неадекватных действий политиков в отношении IT-сферы. При этом: а) следует изучить, как в аналогичных случаях поступали другие в разных странах; б) креативные идеи при таких вопросах оказываются весьма кстати.

Comment: Идеи могут быть разными, от чего-то подобного [**малозаметной плашке «Powered by NGINX»**](https://openmedia.io/infometer/qiwi-headhunter-vkontakte-i-yandex-klyuchevye-it-kompanii-rossii-vstali-na-storonu-nginx/) до [**временного прекращения функционирования сайта**](https://ru.wikimedia.org/wiki/Забастовка_Википедии_на_русском_языке/Пресса). При желании можно [**много чего изучить и придумать**](https://gtmarket.ru/laboratory/expertize/3200/3211).

Comment: Но, видимо, здесь превалирующая позиция — оставаться в стороне от событий внешнего мира, не связанных непосредственно с сайтами сети Stack Exchange. И если сверху внезапно не окажется никого политизированного, затея с превентивным обсуждением мер противодействия политическим решениям, скорее всего, будет обречена на провал. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Я уже всё понял, так как дизы перевешивают и местный бомонд ни как не заинтересован в создании души сообщества. Максимум, что тут можно - антимонийские чатики.

Comment: @doox911, не являюсь участником "антимонийских чатиков", но вот именно такие сообщения в сторону оных и разделяют сообщество, причём не по существу обсуждаемых вопросов, а просто за принятие/неприятие неких убеждений без каких-либо доводов. Поэтому не стоит удивляться голосам против.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, о, «вступаться за» (или, на выбор, «категорически осуждать») «холопов, у которых чубы трещат» — это сколько угодно. это «дерущиеся паны» приветствуют всеми своими руками. // p.s. чтобы я получил уведомление, надо начать набирать мой ник так, как есть, а не так, как вы подумали.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackOverflow это в гораздо большей степени База Знаний, чем сообщество. С одной стороны это может показаться плохим - бездушное пространство, все сами по себе, нету "теплового лампового" чувства. С другой стороны это же и один из компонентов успеха - Вопросы и Ответы на конкретные проблемы без лишней воды (даже на Мете).

---

Тем не менее, был ряд тем, по которым Сеть занимала какую-то позицию:

- [Net Neutrality and Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange)
- [Will Stack Overflow boycott GoDaddy because of their support for SOPA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stack-overflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa)
- [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand)

Comment: Да и политоту не раз тащили: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/1991579.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica спасибо. Хотел найти этот пост тоже

Answer (score 2):

1. Страничники (сайты) ruSO и ruSO Meta **не** про власть.
2. Страничники (сайты) ruSO и ruSO Meta — это **сборник знаний** по вычислительным наукам и о том, как улучшить его.
3. Даже **если** бы 1-е утверждение **было неверно**, то для того чтобы за кого-то вступаться, **нужно обладать** хотя необходимыми **сведениям** по данным случаям. Поддерживать просто исходя из того, что кто-то зарабатывает себе на хлеб таким же образом как и ты, **недостаточное основание** для **заступничества** касательно дел, которыми они занимаются помимо этого.
4. Если кто-то за кого ручается, а этот кто-то подводит поручителя, то отвечает и последний.
5. А так как есть утверждения 1 и 2, то выполнить 3-е условие не представляется возможным.

Дело не в "сам по себе", а в площадке.

Comment: Что такое "Страничник"?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, тоже самое что и паутиностраница или неводограмота, видимо :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP это из какого словаря? ლ(ಠ_ಠ ლ)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica место (site) в Междусетье (Internet), состоящее из связанных между собой страниц.

Comment: @edem хорошо, значит "сайты".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica ага, они, уточнил.

Comment: @edem зачем? Эти выдуманные термины кроме вас никто не использует.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica как бы это не я придумал, а нашёл в Сети, поэтому "никто" это громко сказано.

Comment: @edem покажите ссылочку, что ли. Я ничего внятного нагуглить не смог.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica можно не через Гугл https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&lr=193

Comment: @edem какие-то непрофильные сайты в выдаче от людей, которые не разбираются в предмете. Зачем сюда этот мусор тащить?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica мы вот с вами разбираемся, вот я и пишу. В чём отличие?

Comment: @edem в том, что никто этот термин не использует на ruSO.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica DevOps не использовали и стали. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: Вам тяжело ознакомится с делами? Искренне желаю вам, чтобы беды вроде *сети* , обходили вас стороной. И да, по мимо сети, куча сфабрикованных дел, просто кипит в душе. И смотришь как отбили Голунова и смотришь на наше сообщество...Мне стыдно.

Comment: @doox911 лишь отвечаю почему здесь это не самая подходящая площадка для этого.

Comment: Без поддержки друг друга мы не сообщество. А это просто база знаний - без души.

Comment: @doox911 согласен. Какие предложения?

Comment: К моему сожалению, я пока констатирую факты. Предложения...Наверное первый шаг, я предпринял задав вопрос. Далее хотелось бы увидеть **хоть комментарий** администраторов или специалистов с большим опытом работы или жизненного опыта. Есть проблема и о ней необходимо говорить! Иначе тут так всё ванильнинько, что аж тошнит.

Comment: А лучше ответ, со своей позицией.