# Невозможно дать объективный ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

У меня ещё не было каких-то особо важных тем на обсуждение с сообществом, но эта кажется такой станет.

Уже несколько раз я встречал вопросы, которые собирали пару минусов, голосов на закрытие по причине якобы `"Невозможно дать объективный ответ"`, но я с этим не соглашался, давал толковые ответы и собирал плюсы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1186646/198251), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/987614/198251), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1169372/198251).

На мой взгляд, это потому, что люди не разделяют 2 очень разных направления в вопросах. Первое и реально лишнее – вопросы основанные на субъективных мнениях и порождающие лишь холивары, не несущие осмысленной практической пользы. Например, `"В какую область ИТ лучше идти?"`.

А бывают вопросы **инженерного** плана, зависящие от разных условий, например, `"Какую архитектуру выбрать для решения такой-то задачи?"`. Однозначно, что такие вопросы не имеют одного-единственного верного ответа, есть разные варианты со своими плюсами и минусами. Возможно ответы на такие вопросы иногда будут основываться на личном опыте отвечающего, но если это будет не эмоциональный опыт, а профессиональный, который может быть полезен другим, пролить свет на подводные камни, то это будет лишь хорошо.

Иногда такие вопросы критикуют за недостаток деталей, мол, если описать всё конкретнее, то можно будет подобрать объективно лучшее решение. Но зачастую вопрошающий ещё не понимает предметную область и не может описать важные нюансы; не знает наперёд вариантов развития своей ситуации, или готов изучить разные варианты; а возможно человек просто заинтересовался темой, хочет понять плюсы и минусы разных способов. Поэтому, я считаю, полезно давать ответы не только на узкие вопросы, но и на более общие, которые помогут сформировать представление о предметной области. К слову, на enSO и других сайтах Stack Exchange это популярная практика, и многие мои ответы на такие общие вопросы это по большей части изучение и перевод тамошних; только там и вопросы, и ответы собирают десятки плюсов, у нас же в основном голоса за закрытие `(:` У меня есть много знакомых, которые в связи с этим избегают ruSO и предпочитают задавать вопросы именно на англоязычных сайтах.

Другой момент: вопрошающих отправляют читать книги, чтобы разобраться в теме и сформировать максимально детализированный вопрос. Хотя скорее всего к тому времени вопрос уже решится, но и актуальность в нём тоже пройдёт. Но что ещё плохо – так же можно ответить вообще на всё! И на очень конкретные вопросы, `"пойди почитай учебник/документацию"`. Однако у нас много хороших и детальных ответов даже на общие вопросы вопросы: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427323/198251) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1021/198251) [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460207/198251) [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470453/198251) [5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471343/198251). Это всё выглядит так, будто толковость и объективность вопроса оценивается по качеству ответа к нему и, самое решающее, по рейтингам вопрошающего и отвечающего – это тоже отталкивает людей извне сообщества.

Возможно дело в менталитете – на западе люди легче в общении, проще относятся к разъяснениям ситуаций, обсуждениям разных вариантов; у нас же много суровых технарей, которые такое не очень понимают/принимают, предпочитают в ответе лаконично написать код, зачастую даже без комментариев, и быстро молча уйти. Но блин, если мы творим платформу тире базу знаний, то полезно будет давать ответы и объяснения на важные технические вопросы разных уровней абстракции, лишь бы в них была фактическая польза. Понятно, что не у всех стиль мышления располагает к таким вещам, не у всех есть склонности к преподаванию и разжёвыванию материала, но может хотя бы не надо посредством критики мешать в этом другим?

В связи с этим у меня следующее предложение: быть более конструктивными и стараться отличать общие, инженерные и полезные вопросы от холиварных и бестолковых, писать в комментах не критику, а вопросы-уточнения, в ответах давать базовое описание темы, сравнение основных вариантов решения вопроса, возможно улучшать вопросы делая из `"Какой лучший алгоритм для X?"` нечто более конструктивное вида `"Сравнение алгоритмов для решения X"`, показывая таким образом правильный путь на ruSO, а не просто критикуя за несоответствие.

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша аппеляция к вопросам 1-2-3, как к проблематичным - 1 и 3 не закрыты. Второй закрыт т.к. действительно слишком широк.

Comment: +, все три примера не закрыты по "невозможно дать объективный ответ", т.е. сообщество согласно с тем, что их закрывать по этой причине не надо. Так что пост скорее адресован тем, кто дал эти голоса за закрытие. Вторая часть про отправление читать книги аналогична отправлению в поисковики, т.е. как ответ и причина закрытия -- плохо, как рекомендация прочитать конкретную книгу по теме в комментарии и/или в дополнении к ответу -- нормально

Comment: @Kromster многие из таких вопросов не закрыты как раз потому, что кто-то успел вовремя дать толковый ответ, до этого же они успевают собрать негативные комменты, голоса за закрытие, иногда минусы. То есть, приведённые вопросы выжили не благодаря, а вопреки первичной реакции некоторых участников сообщества. Касательно менее удачных общих, но всё же неплохих вопросов, статистики у меня нет: не нашёл фильтра поиска по закрытым вопросам, а на сайте сижу довольно мало, но боюсь, что их доля стабильная, раз мне регулярно встречаются такие ситуации.

Comment: @AivanF. Всё просто. Голоса за или против, эту сумма субъективных мнений участников находящихся онлайн во время движения вопроса по "небосклону" (др.сл. пока он "виден" большинству). Актуальный состав этих участников зависит от: времени суток, дня недели, положения луны итд. Это приводит к тому, что в зависимости от "фазы видимости" вопроса , хорошие набирают минуса и закрываются, а плохие вдруг заплюсоваются и получают много ответов. Ничего особого делать не надо, просто переоткрывать, голосовать за хорошие вопросы; закрывать и голосовать против плохих. И саморегуляция будет работать.

Comment: @dIm0n Пример вопроса такого типа, но закрытого голосованием. Вопроса, который, как по мне, полезен в сообществе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951478/Какими-знаниями-необходимо-обладать-unity-разработчику/951580#comment1587027_951580

Comment: @Andrew не согласен. Субъективные вопросы отличаются по сути тем, что невозможно сказать, что данный на него ответ правильный. Ответы как на мете оцениваются по категориям нравится/не нравится, а не правильный/неправильный. То есть другой человек может дать противоположный ответ и он не будет неправильным, а ТСу придётся выбирать, какой же вариант ему больше нравится. Таким образом, вопрос останется неотвеченным по сути. В данном случае вы указали в ответе 2 противоположных варианта. Это хорошо, но можно придумать ещё кучу различных "жизненных путей" для ТСа, они тоже не будут неправильными

Comment: @dIm0n я выдал человеку ту информацию, которую обычно он нигде не услышит. Как минимум, это полезно знать перед тем как делать важный выбор в жизни. И вопрос относится к программированию да и в общем и целом он важен для многих будущих программистов. Я практически уверен, подобным вопросом задавался и ты когда-то. И прекрасно если тебе кто-то высветил плюсы и минусы как это сделал в ответе я, а не просто сказал "вопрос плохой, разбирайся сам". Но большинство людей просто плывут по течению не понимая, даже, из чего именно они делают выбор и какие результаты получат в итоге.

Comment: @Andrew я не спорю про полезность вопроса/ответа в целом. Я спорю с тем, что такие вопросы/ответы нужны на этом ресурсе, который позиционируется как база знаний с вопросами по программированию и системному администрированию. Как учиться, куда идти работать, нужен ли универ, нужна ли математика программисту и прочие подобные холиварные вопросы тут не нужны. (хоть это было в 16-17 лет, я прекрасно понимал, что решать свою судьбу на следующие 4-5 лет мне стоит самостоятельно, а не с помощью случайных людей из интернета, поэтому не задавал таких вопросов :))

Answer (score 9):

Как я считаю, возможная причина появления голосов на закрытие упомянутых постов в том, что часто ruSO рассматривается исключительно как калька с большого SO (ограничивая соответствующую тематику и форму вопросов). На enSO вопросы так называемого инженерного плана вполне себе можно перенести на другие сайты сети, например, на [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), это даже сразу понятно из названия. Очевидно, что при переносе вопрос на первичном сайте закрывается. Соответствующих русскоязычных сайтов внутри сети SE нет. Переносить некуда. Поэтому вариантов исхода меньше: либо вопрос просто закрывается (теми, кто считает, что он не подходит в текущем виде для ruSO), при этом с возможностью быть переоткрытым (другими неравнодушными людьми, или даже переубеждёнными первыми), либо номинально остаётся открытым. В последнем случае сыграть роль могут как наличие уже заплюсованных ответов, упоминание того, что ruSO != enSO и тематика у него немножечко шире, ну или даже публикация или ссылка на соответствующее предложение о расширении существующей тематики ruSO, чтобы текущий вопрос под неё подходил.

При этом хочу заметить, что наличие как таковых сообщений с позитивными оценками слабо коррелирует с соответствием сообщений правилам сайта. Сообщение может быть интересным, но более подходящим для сайтов другого плана, например, всевозможных форумов или какой-нибудь Quora. Чего стоят только [диалоги-о-работе](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5) на Мете. С моим  [ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5815/176217) оттуда, кстати, вполне будет интересно ознакомиться и в составе обсуждения текущего вопроса.

Comment: Вот и я примерно о том, чтобы коллеги здесь спокойнее относились к широте тем и общности вопросов, а то некоторые ведут себя так, будто если на вопрос нельзя ответить куском кода или однозначной и строгой инструкцией, то вопрос надо закрывать, а спрашивающего посылать куда-нибудь подальше.

Comment: А насколько широким может быть диапазон тем? Вопросы про установку ОС? Про ошибки запуска IDE? Давайте тогда пересматривать то какие вопросы можно задавать здесь и о чем наш ресурс. В сети есть форумы и ресурсы более подходящие для вопросов вне тематики ruSO и вполне себе живые.

Comment: @NikolajSarry диапазон тем обозначен на [странице справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) и в случае чего должен обновляться ответственными сотрудниками. О предложениях изменения онтопичных тем надо создавать отдельные вопросы на Мете, с добавлением метки [meta-tag:тематика].