# Почему так тяжело получить знак "Альтруист"?

Tags: поддержка, знаки, конкурс

Изучая знаки и способы получение знаков, я заметил один удивительный знак под название "Альтруист" В теории это должен быть самый распространённый знак, ведь чтобы его получить нужно всего лишь: **"Первая награда, которую вы вручаете за ответ на вопрос другого участника"**. Получается нужно просто ответит на вопрос другого участника. Этот знак даже помечен, как  `Бронзовый знак`, что значит его легко получить.

Однако встает большое **"НО"**. Почему данный знак получило всего 124 человек? В теории у половина сайта должен быть такой знак, т.к. чтоб его получить, надо просто ответить на вопрос другого участника. Чтоб вы понимали, знак  `Знаменитый вопрос`, который выдается за **"Вопрос с 10000 просмотров"** и помечен как `Золотой знак`, что значит он редкий. **Но его получило 5327 человек, что в 42 раза больше, чем знак с пометкой  `Бронзовый знак`!!!**. И главный вопрос: "Почему так?".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это про [конкурсные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81/info) вопросы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, тогда почему эта информация не написана инструкции, как получить знак?

Comment: Сложности перевода. Но если поискать по Мете слово [награда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0), то ситуация может проясниться.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо, я получил ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: `почему эта информация не написана инструкции, как получить знак?` Именно это в инструкции и написано: «Первая **награда, которую вы вручаете** за ответ на вопрос другого участника».

Comment: @wololo, но там вообще ничего не написано про конкурсные вопросы.

Comment: Там сказано про _награду_, которую вы вручаете. О какой награде по вашему идёт речь?

Comment: Если брать данную строчку:  «... которую вы вручаете за ответ на вопрос другого участника», то значит это я выдаю награду участнику? @wololo

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty : «Награда – это репутация, которая вручается за ответы. Она присуждается из личной репутации пользователя, который начинает конкурс, и не может быть изъята обратно.»

Comment: Речь идет о награде: "Альтруист".@wololo

Comment: `которую вы вручаете за ответ на вопрос другого участника», то значит это я выдаю награду участнику? Речь идет о награде: "Альтруист".`  Если я правильно понял вашу мысль: я награждаю другого участника знаком «Альтруист», за то, что я написал ему ответ? Странная интерпретация. Возможно, слово «награда» в описании знака просто следует сделать гиперссылкой на соответствующую страницу справки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151026/discussion-between-nymos-and-wololo).

Comment: Мне больше интересно: зачем вообще гоняться за значками? Они же ничего не дают совершенно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так прикольно же. У меня триста значков, у него двести, значит я круче)

Comment: Почему тяжело? Наоборот, очень легко получить. Количество имеющих этот значок никак не говорит о сложности или легкости его получения.

Comment: @Эникейщик не то чтобы тяжело, из за сложного перевода не понятно, как получить знак,

Comment: Да все понятно. Что там может быть непонятного-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик лично я не знал, что только за конкурсные вопросы, ведь там не написано об этом

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, слушай, а я могу спрашивать просто советы в stackoverflow в вопросе?

Comment: Скорее всего, нет. Но могут быть [нюансы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10907/176217).

Comment: @Nymos в чате можете https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[из комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13177/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82#comment57159_13177):

> Из-за сложности перевода. Но если поискать по Мете слово [награда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0), то ситуация может проясниться.