# Перевод /help/how-to-ask

Tags: предложение, локализация

Страница [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) выглядит заметно короче её аналога [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

В частности отсутствует раздел "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" («Заголовку следует быть выжимкой проблемы»). Учитывая, что вопросы с чересчур размытыми заголовками не редки. Полезно ссылку было бы иметь, в которой описано, почему «Python ошибка» заголовок является cлишком общим и что следует его на более специфичный заменить. Пример параграфа:

> **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem? Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

Перевод:

> Представьте, что вы обращаетесь к занятому коллеге и вынуждены выразить весь вопрос в одном предложении: какие детали вы можете включить, которые помогут опознать и решить проблему? Добавьте любые сообщения об ошибке, ключевые API (имена существенных библиотек/сервисов/функций/классов/итд) или необычные обстоятельства, которые делают ваш вопрос отличным от других похожих вопросов на сайте.

Есть ли особые причины, что не включён этот раздел? Нужна ли помощь с переводом? (если я не ошибаюсь, эти разделы доступны для редакции модераторам)

Comment: Эти разделы вроде как только Nicolas править может.

Comment: @Suvitruf поправить — задача инструментальная, легкая. Модераторы тоже могут.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похоже, перевод устарел. Давайте дополним. Оригинальный текст — внутри, в комментариях.

---

Вот несколько советов, позволяющих **увеличить шансы** на получение ответа:

### [Ищите](/search) и изучайте

Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили **[тщательный поиск ответа](/search)**. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа!

### Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке

Заголовок — это первое, что увидят читатели, которые могут ответить на ваш вопрос. Если заголовок неинтересный, они не будут читать дальше. Каждое слово на счету:

- **Представьте, что вы обращаетесь к занятому коллеге** и вынуждены выразить весь вопрос в одном предложении: какие детали вы можете включить, которые помогут опознать и решить проблему? Добавьте любые сообщения об ошибке, ключевые API (имена существенных библиотек/сервисов/функций/классов/итд) или необычные обстоятельства, которые делают ваш вопрос отличным от других похожих вопросов на сайте.
- **Пишите грамотно!** Помните, эту часть вашего вопроса увидят в первую очередь — она должна произвести хорошее впечатление.
- Если поначалу вам трудно описать проблему в одном предложении, **придумайте заголовок в последнюю очередь**. Когда вы напишете сам вопрос, вам будет проще сформулировать заголовок.

Размытый заголовок без деталей затрудняет поиск решения будущими посетителями из поисковиков с похожей проблемой ([основная аудитория Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/)), делая вопрос менее полезным, и может уменьшить шансы на ответ и/или привлечь голос «против» (минус).

Примеры:

- **Плохо:** Непонятно как работает математика в C#.
- **Хорошо:** Почему если использовать float вместо int, результаты вычислений отличаются, хотя все вводимые числа — целые?
- **Плохо:** Сессии в [php]
- **Хорошо:** Как перенаправлять пользователей на различные страницы в зависимости от данных сессии в PHP?
- **Плохо:** Проблема с условиями в Android
- **Хорошо:** Почему str == "value" ложно, когда str имеет значение "value"?

### Сначала опишите проблему, потом добавьте код

Сначала более подробно опишите проблему, которую вы сформулировали в заголовке.
Поясните, как вы столкнулись с проблемой и что препятствует её решению.
После заголовка, первый абзац — самая часто читаемая часть вопроса.
Дайте в нём максимум информации, чтобы заинтересовать читателей.

### Расскажите, как воспроизвести проблему

Если ваша проблема связана с написанным вами кодом, обязательно добавьте код.
Не копируйте вашу программу целиком!
Во-первых, есть риск, что вы опубликуете закрытый код, принадлежащий вашему работодателю.
Во-вторых, в нем будет много лишнего, что не относится к вашей проблеме.

Как сделать хороший пример кода:

- Добавьте ровно столько кода, сколько нужно, чтобы воспроизвести проблему.
  Прочитайте об этом подробнее: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve)
- Если можете — сделайте запускаемый пример кода и дайте ссылку на сайт (например, на http://sqlfiddle.com/ или http://jsbin.com/).
  Обязательно добавьте тот же код и в сам вопрос.
  Сайт может быть недоступен для читателей, а ссылка со временем может устареть.

### Отметьте вопрос всеми подходящими метками

Добавьте метку языка, используемой библиотеки или конкретного API, к которым относится ваш вопрос.
Напишите часть названия в поле для меток и сайт предложит вам подходящие метки.
Прочитайте описания меток и убедитесь, что они соответствуют теме вашего вопроса.
Подробнее о метках читайте в справке: [Что такое метки и как их использовать?](/help/tagging)

### Сначала перечитайте, потом публикуйте

Когда вопрос готов, перечитайте его ещё раз с самого начала.
Представьте, что видите его впервые.
Всё ли вам понятно?

Воспроизведите проблему по инструкции из вопроса в чистом окружении.
Хватило ли вам для этого информации в вопросе?
Если нет — добавьте в него недостающее и снова перечитайте.

Проверьте, что заголовок по-прежнему точно описывает проблему.

### Опубликуйте вопрос и отвечайте на комментарии

Когда опубликуете вопрос, оставьте открытой вкладку браузера и следите за комментариями.
Если вас попросят добавить информацию или уточнить вопрос — отредактируйте его и добавьте нужное.
Проверяйте каждый опубликованный ответ и пишите комментарии о том, что у вас получилось.

---

> Этого уже нет в англоязычной версии.

### Будьте в теме

Наше сообщество следует ряду правил общения на форуме. Чтобы знать, какие темы можно обсуждать, [ознакомьтесь с разделом справки](/help/on-topic); пожалуйста, придерживайтесь этих правил и [избегайте вопросов-опросников, а также тем, порождающих бесцельные дискуссии](/help/dont-ask). Если вопрос касается самого сайта, задайте его на Мета. Если ваш вопрос не соответствует тематике нашего сайта, возможно, вам помогут на [другом сайте Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

### Будьте точны

Если вы зададите нечеткий вопрос, то можете получить такой же нечеткий ответ. Подробное и точное изложение проблемы увеличивает возможность получить исчерпывающий ответ.

### Пусть ваш вопрос будет полезен другим

Хорошо, когда ваш вопрос актуален, полезен не только вам, но и другим пользователям, которые так же, как и вы, будут заинтересованы в получении быстрого и правильного ответа.

### Не будьте предвзяты

Ответ на ваш вопрос не всегда может вам понравиться, но это не означает, что он неверный. Иногда тяжело найти окончательное, неоспоримое решение. В спорных или сомнительных случаях попросите участников обсуждения пояснить, на чем основаны их утверждения, дать ссылки на источники. Но даже если с вами несогласны или вы услышали не то, что хотели, помните: вам просто пытаются помочь.

Comment: Если возражений нет по части с заголовком, то какие дальнейшие действия, чтобы обновить /help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: @jfs там внутри ещё пара разделов не переведена, я собираюсь завтра их перевести и тогда опубликую. Ваши правки видел, поддерживаю.

Comment: @jfs завал на работе, откладываю до выходных.

Comment: есть возможность просто copy-paste сделать того что есть?

Comment: @jfs опубликовал кроме последнего раздела.

Comment: замечательно.  С помощью  `[ask]` сослался на описание какой и почему заголовок создавать, чтобы не пытаться в комментариях к вопросам  всё уместить. 2- может ещё ссылку на [custom google search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) добавить (проще чем встроенным новым людям пользоваться и больше находит) 3- непереведённые части для ясности из комментариев в ответе здесь можно вытащить (чтобы они видны были