# Что делать, если человек спрашивает готовое решение задачи с контрольной или зачёта?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Многие люди постят сюда вопросы с контрольных или зачётов. С моей точки зрения писать готовое решение в таком случае — это, по сути, навредить человеку, сделать для него халяву и лишить его возможности научиться тому, чему он обучается. Какое мнение сообщества на тему того как надо/не надо отвечать на просьбу получить готовое решение на подобные задачи?

Как я сам думаю, что если человек сделал, например 70, 80, 90% и просто не понимает, что у него не получается или не работает, тогда можно помочь. Процент я просто написал, может быть и 50%, не в этом суть. Но писать 100% за человека готовое решение, по-моему, это неправильно.

Это один момент. И второй момент — даже, если я такое сообщение пропущу, ведь может кто-то другой, кто, например, просто баллы хочет набрать, может ответить, и тогда, опять же, получается вред.

Comment: imho, вы преувеличиваете "вред" и в целом берете на себя решать *за кого-то*, что ему "вред", а что - польза. Не забывайте, что вопросы от студентов - это вопросы от вполне совершеннолетних людей. Которые вправе сами решать, хотят они учится, или нет. Если, с вашей точки зрения, писать за кого-то на 100% готовое решение - неправильно - то вывод очень простой - не пишите. Кто-то другой ответит - ок, этот "кто-то" наберется опыта. Это значительно перевешивает "вред" кому-то, кто не удосужился попробовать найти решение самостоятельно, но о котором вы так трогательно заботитесь :)

Answer (score 3):

Если у автора вопроса были хоть какие-то попытки, то я могу и помочь. Но если это просто скопированное задание без толики рассуждений и т.п, то закрываю как "учебное задание".

Необязательно прикладывать код, достаточно хотя бы рассуждений, чтобы понять, что человек уже сделал, и где у него проблема.

Comment: То есть мне как не модератору можно жаловаться на такие сообщения?

Comment: Можно (и нужно) голосовать за закрытие таких вопросов, да.

Comment: Лучше не усердствуйте с флагами, наберёте 3000 репутации - вам будет доступен инструмент голосования за закрытие вопросов.

Comment: @vp_arth ох, точно. Совсем забыл про то, что для голосования репа нужна =/

Comment: если вопрос полезен для будущих посетителей из гугла — основной источник трафика и основная целевая аудитория ([критерии качества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)), то наличие отвлекающих попыток оригинального автора вопроса не помогает. Но крайне вероятно, что вопрос-копия задания не будет полезным, так как будет списком нескольких вопросов или иметь ограничения, не встречающиеся на практике. С другой стороны, если вопрос всё-таки полезный, то моральный облик автора, его предполагаемая лень, "вред" личному развитию автора из-за информативного ответа  — не имеют значения.

Comment: @jfs так и? Вам этим ленивцам никто помогать не запрещает же, я лишь сказал, что я таким людям вряд ли будут помогать. Ваш поинт с "польза сообществу превыше всего" понятен, конечно.

Comment: @Suvitruf странно что человек, который добровольно выдвигался в модераторы не разделяет целей сайта. К чему закрывать полезные вопросы? В сторону: это мелочь, но под пользой я понимаю пользу для посетителей сайта из гугла. Слово "сообщество" для меня подразумевает активных участников: какая польза для нас с вами—это отдельная тема.

Comment: @jfs отвечать на вопрос или нет - это, пока ещё, моё личное решение. И мои взгляды на этот счёт необязательно должны сходиться с большинством. Если вопрос действительно стоящий, то найдётся тот, кто ответит на него.

Comment: @Suvitruf *«закрываю как "учебное задание"»* или вы считаете, что исключительно бесполезные вопросы как учебные задания задают или вы пытаетесь помешать *другим* ответить на полезный вопрос.

Comment: @jfs я уже сказал, не все учебные вопросы плохие. Ну и да, от одного моего голоса вопрос не будет закрыт. А если хватило голосов на закрытие такого вопроса, то значит сообщество такого же мнения, что и я. Нет? К тому же, вопрос всегда можно переоткрыть.

Comment: @Suvitruf: *"не все учебные вопросы плохие"* -- такие нюансы большинству голосующих за закрытие не доступны: увидел "учебное задание" -- закрыл (а полезен, не полезен вопрос, уже мало кого волнует). Правда вопрос существования подобной причины закрытия не к вам -- управляющему сообществом следовало видение сайта защищать.

Comment: @jfs это отдельная тема. Мне не только эта причина закрытия не нравится. И уже много раз поднимались обсуждения, но толку всегда ноль.

Comment: как раз проблема в том, ввели вредное изменение (толк есть, но не в ту сторону) чтобы помочь участникам борющимся за моральную чистоту и личное развитие авторов вопросов.