# Вопросы в виде картинок

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Признаюсь честно, не пытался искать, задавался ли такой вопрос ранее или нет. Но мне хотелось бы поднять его на обсуждение. Вот стандартная формулировка:

> данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он
> бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не
> сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

И пошли голоса за закрытие. И очень вероятно, что такой вопрос будет закрыт. Но давайте попробуем разобраться более детально. Для примера возьмем один из последних таких вопросов: [Как сделать такую структуру флекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1258346/377637)

Автору необходимо реализовать на практике некую структуру. Сразу оговоримся, что для этой реализации необходим `HTML` и `CSS` код. Но, очевидно же, что если автор понятия не имеет, каким образом можно создать такую, на его взгляд, сложную структуру, то какой код он может нам предоставить? Ответ очевиден — никакого. Поэтому у него есть только один выход — изобразить требуемое в виде картинки. И эту картинку он оформляет в своем вопросе. Других вариантов у него, увы, нет. Но согласитесь, картинка уже является некой работой, которую автор выполнил своими силами, и это уже похвально. И не важно, структура `HTML` это, какая-то фигура, или что-то другое. Вопросы в виде картинок бывают разными, каждый из них индивидуален. Признаюсь, я и сам такие вопросы с картинками недолюбливаю, но при этом понимаю, что чаще всего бывает так, что кроме картинки автору и приложить-то к вопросу фактически больше нечего. Поэтому с терпением и пониманием отношусь к таким вопросам и отвечаю на них.

Теперь хотелось бы поговорить о том, полезны ли такие вопросы для нашей базы знаний, или нет. Сразу, не раздумывая, можно выстрелить — нет. Точнее будет сказано — чаще всего нет. Чаще всего, но не всегда потому, что такая вероятность, что хотя бы один человек да найдется, кому необходимо будет подобное решением, возможно есть. Да, кто-то может сказать, что такая полезность нам вовсе не нужна. Однако, с таким утверждением я не совсем могу согласиться, потому что считаю, что если хотя бы один пользователь нашел для себя в каком-то подобном вопросе что-то полезное, то такой вопрос уже является полезным для базы знаний, и это уже маленькая, но наша общая победа.

Согласитесь со мной, что большая часть всех вопросов и ответов решает исключительно личные потребности тех пользователей, которые задают вопросы, и такие вопросы с ответами являются практически бесполезными для других пользователей, равно как и для базы знаний. С таких вопросов реально взять абсолютно нечего, потому что они слишком узки, специфичны, и к себе это при всё желании никак не прикрутишь. Но такие вопросы мы почему-то не закрываем. А вопросы в виде картинок рьяно начинаем закрывать.

Возможно, я что-то не понимаю. В таком случае, пожалуйста, меня поправьте. Но к сожалению очевидно, что у нас нет единого и утвержденного решения по таким вопросам. Потому что одни участники утверждают, что такие вопросы мы не закрываем, а другие их фактически закрывают. Поэтому прошу не закрывать мой вопрос и не отмечать его как дубликат, если вдруг таковой имеется. Хотелось бы услышать и другие мнения на этот счет. Ну и конечно же прийти к какому-то единому решению — на будущее закрываем мы вопросы в виде картинок или нет. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Мне кажется надо просто различать картинки с кодом (скриншот кода в редакторе) от прочих картинок. Картинки первого типа закрываем, остальные нет (особенно, если к ним есть сопровождающий текст)

Comment: @avp, однозначно, я не имею ввиду картинки, которые - скриншот кода в редакторе. Здесь я сразу люто голосую за закрытие таких вопросов и минусую их. Но... крайне редко, но бывают исключения, когда вижу, что это единственный вариант показать проблему.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, просил же не отмечать этот вопрос как дубликат, если таковой вдруг имеется, а обсудить его и прийти к какому-то единому взаимному решению, чтобы в дальнейшем к этому не возвращаться. Что же вы за люди то такие?

Comment: Вопрос явный дубликат, какой смысл его обсуждать второй раз здесь? Мы же не создаем дубликаты на основном сайте, если ответ на первый вопрос нас не укстроил. Обсуждайте вопрос там и все дела.

Comment: @tym32167 вот как раз «если ответ на первый вопрос нас не укстроил» — тогда и создаём :) Но, конечно, с обязательным пояснением, чем именно не устроил

Comment: @tym32167, Андрей совершенно прав. В синем окошке что написано? `Ваше сообщение было объединено со схожим вопросом. Если этот вопрос не решает вашей проблемы, задайте новый вопрос.`. Вот и задаем новый вопрос. И причем в вопросе имеются пояснения - что не решено, что нужно решить, и главное почему и зачем. Со своей стороны я выполнил все правила в полном объеме. Но не смотря на это, мой вопрос закрыли. И я так полагаю, что закрывающие нарочно саботируют эту тему.

Comment: Впервые слышу, что можно создавать дубликаты просто потому, что считаешь, что ответы в оригинальных вопросах недостаточно хороши. Кто то из нас явно неверно трактует правила. То, о чем вы пишете, противоречит тому, что я  видел на основном сайте. Я не думаю, что вопрос закрыло тайное общество противников картинок, например, я отдал голос так как посчитал вопрос дубликатом, а не потому, что хочу что то саботировать.

Comment: @tym32167, `Впервые слышу, что можно создавать дубликаты просто потому, что считаешь, что ответы в оригинальных вопросах недостаточно хороши.` - впервые слышите? А где и от кого вы такое слышали?

Comment: @tym32167 об этом даже в справке написано: [«нам нравятся (некоторые) дубликаты»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) (и там ссылка на интересный пост в английском блоге SO)

Comment: @andreymal хах, а вот это уже интересно. Спасибо! Почитаю на досуге

Answer (score 1):

Одна из наиболее важных характеристик базы знаний — **возможность найти вопрос**. Вопрос должен иметь **текстовое** описание, чтобы он хорошо индексировался в поисковиках и был полезен для других людей, а не только для автора.

Никто не будет гуглить запросы вида «flex сделать такое», зато будут гуглить [«как сделать flex-элемент высотой в две строки»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365433) или как вариант [«поместить два flex-элемента в одну строку»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705266).

По этой причине [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) делает особый акцент на заголовке вопроса:

> Заголовок — это первое, что увидят читатели, которые могут ответить на ваш вопрос. [...] Размытый заголовок без деталей затрудняет поиск решения будущими посетителями из поисковиков с похожей проблемой ([основная аудитория Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4181)), делая вопрос менее полезным, и может уменьшить шансы на ответ и/или привлечь голос «против» (минус).

Заголовок «Как сделать такую структуру флекс» — определённо плохой.

Пока в вопросе не появится текстового описания задачи — его никто не сможет найти и он **бесполезен для базы знаний**.

Посему Victor и Qwertiy неправы, а я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121089/discussion-on-answer-by-andreymal----).

Answer (score 0):

Нормальный вопрос. Картинки с кодом/ошибками это не удобно для отвечающих и искать невозможно. А другие картинки — ок, без них не обойтись иногда.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121081/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-vosmottor----).

Answer (score 0):

Причина с картинками должна использоваться только когда код (или другой текст) предоставлен в виде скриншота или фотографии экрана. Для вопросов по лейаутам и всяким схемам она использоваться не должна. А приведённый вопрос нормальный и не должен закрываться.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121080/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----).