# Смена порога голосов для закрытия

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

Сейчас для закрытия вопроса нужно 5 голосов. Из-за низкой активности в очереди закрытия вопросы остаются висеть с 3-4 голосами максимум, голоса сгорают - и механизм очередей и закрытия не работает.

Может быть стоит снизить порог голосов до 3-х, как это сделано на enSO?

Comment: Очень хочется всё закрыть?

Comment: @Sevastopol' нет, но очень хочется чтобы на мете обсуждались предложения, которые проскакивали в комментариях к соседним обсуждениям, а не то, чего мне хочется, а чего - нет.

Comment: Не надо, а то опять начнется....

Comment: Как по мне, так я даже увеличил бы количество голосов за закрытие/переоткрытие, но при этом, добавив голосам "вес" на основе репутации/знаков/меток.

Answer (score -3):

Пусть так и остаётся 5, а то некоторые любители закрывать набросятся и всё позакрывают. Не надо нам закрывать всё подряд.

Comment: Так на переоткрытие тоже будет 3, видимо.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Если вопрос нормальный, интересный и закрыт, не глядя, не вникая, по формальным признакам, типа - заголовки одинаковые, и закрыт в погоне за медальками "Ревизор", то он и легко открывается 5 -тью голосами

Comment: За "закрывать все подряд" должны модераторы следить, и бить по рукам, вплоть до блокировки. В очереди на закрытие 600+ вопросов, и меньше 5 проверяющих. Она не работает. Может быть понимание, что каждый голос в очереди более решающий, чем раньше, хоть немного подтолкнет ее разгребать :)

Comment: @PashaPash просто есть некоторые участники, которые **вообще** против функционала закрытия, ну кроме как что дубликатами, наверное. Поэтому неработающая очередь выглядит для них как благо.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я тоже не слишком за, просто предложение рядом в комментариях проскакивало, собрало плюсы - решил вынести на обсуждение :)

Comment: Так и запишем: модераторы выступают за замусоривание сайта плохими вопросами

Comment: а разве закрывается все подряд?

Comment: @Эникейщик да, иногда вопросы попадают по закрытие по желанию левой пятки закрывающего. Вот простой пример - один участник решил, что вопросы вида "как сверстать такое <картинка>" нужно закрывать - и закрывает с причиной "данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть". Вот так взял и решил за всех, что вопросы по верстке - оффтопик - и заверте. и закрывают жеж - вот, внезапно теперь вот это - домашнее задание: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1327551/177221 а вот это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1314621/177221 - необходимо конкретизировать

Comment: Qwertiy, конкретный участник явно игнорирует обсуждение на мете (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11441/177221), и закрывает онтопичные вопросы. а потом нытье на мете "ой, что-то вопросов мало". нехорошо как-то :)

Comment: @PashaPash По желанию **пяти** участников, а не одного.

Comment: @Эникейщик ага, при этом еще один из них пользуется автокликером, а еще пара явно не читала причину закрытия. ну типа - вопрос же в очереди, топовый разгребатель очереди (и основной закрыватель всего) сказал закрыть - он же не может ошибаться. надо закрыть.

Comment: @Эникейщик вот еще "домашнее задание": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294576/. Притом что причина вводилась для закрытия копипастнутых задач от студентов. тут, имхо, модераторам надо проводить разъяснительные беседы с закрывающими.

Comment: @PashaPash вроде тут уже обсуждали, что причину про домашки можно применять к любым вопросам типа "как сделать такое, сам я не пробовал и вообще ничего не знаю",

Comment: @Эникейщик оба вопроса выше под это точно не попадают, там авторы явно пробовали решить сами, и не просят решить за них.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну и при введении причины закрытия домашек сообщество било себя пяткой в грудь что это исключительно для закрытия ленивого копипаста задач, и что все смогут отличить копипаст условия «сделайте за меня» от нормальных вопросов. А теперь пытаются натянуть эту причину на онтопичные вопросы.

Comment: тут намёки на мою позицию, причём в явно искажённом её виде. ещё раз повторюсь: проблему вопросов-картинок я вижу отнюдь не в наличии описывающей суть вопроса картинки, а в отсутствии описывающего суть вопроса **текста**. // и, кстати, не понял вот этого момента: `конкретный участник явно игнорирует обсуждение на мете`. речь явно именно про меня, но в чём же состоит моё «игнорирование обсуждения»? в том, что не написал в том вопросе ничего? ну так я проголосовал за/против вопрос/ответы и за закрытие вопроса как дубликата.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну ты ж умеешь пользоваться `@`. Почему твой коммент написан без неё, а следовательно относится ко мне, хотя я ничего такого не говорил?

Comment: Qwertiy, и правда. исправляюсь: @PashaPash

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну ок, не игнорирует - значит ситуация еще интереснее. сообщество решило, что большая часть вопросов по верстке - оффтопик, и закрывает их. как домашку. а потом ноет на мете, что SO умирает. HTML - не полный по Тьюрингу, верстка - не настоящее программирование, любой вопрос с картинкой без детального описания каждого элемента картинки - оффтопик. такие дела.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если прямо - то "он бесполезен для базы знаний" не может быть валидной причиной закрытия. SO - не база знаний. "Этот сайт посвящён исключительно **получению ответов**". (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour). "другие потом не смогут найти ответ" никак не может быть валидной причиной закрытия. И до тех пор, пока в онтопик не впишут пункт про "должна быть возможность найти ответ через гугл" - закрытие онтопичных вопросов по левой причине - это нарушение правил. Которое должно пресекаться модераторами. Закрытие их как "домашки" - тем более.

Comment: @PashaPash, большая часть — это явно не про меня: у меня нет предубеждения против вопросов по вёрстке (в том числе — никогда не придирался к отсутствию «детального описания каждого элемента картинки»), я не «ною на мете об умирании сайта», я против причины закрытия «домашка» [**по крайней мере в текущей формулировке**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8979/178576).

Comment: @PashaPash,  по поводу вопросов-картинок — я множество раз (в комментариях к ответам на эти вопросы) призывал авторов ответов к тому, чтобы они **дополняли** вопросы текстовым описанием проблемы: во-первых, у них это может получиться даже лучше, чем у автора вопроса: они явно лучше владеют предметной областью, во-вторых, сайт их к этому поощряет (есть отдельная награда за правку вопросов, на которые ответил). // но чаще всего встречал у таких авторов ответов негативную реакцию: мол, я ответ дал, а вопрос пусть в порядок приводит кто-нибудь другой. потому и бросил это гиблое дело.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну и пара слов по поводу целей сайта: такой вопрос-картинка как правило тривиален, и ответы на него сыпятся как из рога изобилия. поэтому **автор вопроса** ответ-то как раз получает. а вот для тех, кто попытается найти ответы на точно такой же вопрос, эти уже написанные ответы фактически не существуют. и он, даже потратив время на поиски (естественно, словами — поисковики не умеют «парсить» картинки), вновь задаст точно такой же вопрос. но самое печальное здесь то, что и дубликат найти невозможно — из-за отсутствия этого самого текстового описания. круг замыкается.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin декларируемая цель сайта - возможность получить ответ на свой вопрос. Найти уже существующий - вторично. Для вопросов по верстке поиск существующих ответов часто невозможен - мало того, что для этого нужно чтобы существующий вопрос был подробно описан, так еще и формулировка у ищущего должна совпасть и оказаться настолько близкой и уникальной, чтобы попасть на первую страницу гугла. Ну т.е. шанс - 0, даже если автор вопроса распишет все подробно и текстом.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin но я вообще не про онтопичность, а про использование механизма закрытия. Вопросы закрываются для автора, и критерий закрытия - для получения объективно верного ответа в вопросе не хватает какой-то информации, которую может добавить только автор. "не хватает текстового описания картинки, чтобы поисковик мог проиндексировать для каких-то абстрактных будущих посетителей", очевидно, такой информацией не является.

Comment: @PashaPash, всё-таки насчёт цели сайта не всё так однозначно. даже если ориентироваться лишь на [краткое описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour): «Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе **мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов** на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.» (выделено мной). продолже.ие следует.

Comment: страница tour написана для новичков. понятно, что про базу знаний («библиотеку ответов») в ней упомянуто на втором плане. но мы-то не новички, и уже знаем, что «для посмотреть» на сайт приходят на порядки больше людей, чем «для спросить». // по поводу критериев закрытия и для кого они предназначены — напишу позже: надо ещё обдумать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1936/177221 . Причина закрытия должна быть призывом к действию для задавшего вопрос. Библиотека это хорошо, но по факту у нас просто почти не структурированная куча вопросов, с надеждой, что гугл в нее приведет кого-нибудь. В 99% вопросов гугл не приведет никогда, и пытаться пару десятков из них отфильтровать вручную - это пустая трата времени. Они в базе лежат, есть не просят, и от закрытия их никому лучше не станет. С домашками кстати та же история. :(