# Субботник на ru SO

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, ответы

Мы тут жарко [обсуждали отклонять правки-приветствия или нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4386/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). А может давайте просто устоим субботник и уберём причину для раздора? Почистим все старые вопросы (поредактируем как можно), поудаляем всё, что не надо. Удалим все приветствия, будем форматировать код и т.д. Удалим ненужные теги.

Просто без обязаловки и бессрочно. Кто сколько вопросов может в день. Если каждый будет по 10-20 вопросов править в день, то так со временем и не останется "неухоженых" вопросов и ответов.

---

Также важно: мы сможем параллельно добавлять новые ответы (которые просто лучше или актуальней), улучшая качество базы знаний. Также пометим некоторые дубликатами и т.д., позакрываем некорректные.

---

Если мы будем к этому равнодушны, то с нами всегда будут тянуться "неопрятные" вопросы с 2011 года. Неужели нам нужен такой шлейф? А вместе веселей и быстрей будет.

Answer (score 9):

Учитывая, что зарплату тут получает только один человек, можно сказать, что субботник и так происходит каждый день. Перефразируя классиков: субботник начинается в понедельник. Поэтому устраивать какую-то принудиловку (даже если сказано "без обязаловки и бессрочно") просто бессмысленно. Это идёт вразрез с основными идеями сайта, а ещё - нарушает права человека.

Comment: Ну так роботам боятся нечего ;) Хотя, возможно, тогда это значит, что у них нет прав вообще xD

Comment: Можно подумать, я потом буду спрашивать с кого-либо, даже если мы на это решимся. Никакой принудиловки, просто просьба. Вы лично можете в этом не участвовать, если не хотите.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov не участвовать в чём? Каждый присутствующий на сайте человек и так уже участвует в предложенном Вами субботнике в соответствии со своими возможностями и интересами с учётом ограничений системы.

Comment: @alexolut Не согласен насчёт каждый. Почему вы решили, что именно *каждый* человек в этом участвует? И я вёл речь именно про старые вопросы, а не новые. И если мы коллективно возьмёмся и активно поработаем, то многое исправим.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov идеология SO подразумевает участие каждого. Если кто-то не делает правок, то, скорее всего, ему это просто не интересно. Когда репутация позволяет и есть желание, то ждать массового старта совершенно ненужная трата времени. Можно идти и делать. Или Вы опасаетесь порицания сообщества на Ваши действия без предварительного одобрения большинства?

Answer (score 6):

На очень ранних стадиях развития проекта мы проводили подобные мероприятия силами администрации (модераторов и разработчиков). Обычно, мы проводили чистку два раза в год, после летней и зимней сессий. Задача была в поддержании высокого качества базы знаний. На сегодняшний момент, на сайте задается [чуть менее 200 вопросов в день в среднем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4160/), что эквивалентно 6К в месяц и 36К за полгода. Просмотреть подобный объем сообщений, на мой взгляд, не представляется возможным.

Выход, все же, есть.

#### Необходимо [активно участвовать в ежедневной модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4209/): голосовать за и против; участвовать в закрытии и удалении плохих вопросов и ответов).

Идея базируется на функционале [автоматического удаления «заброшенных вопросов»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/). По сути, «это робо–субботник». Если сообщество активно участвует в модерации, система должна автоматически разобраться со всем ненужным шумом.

Если все–таки что–то пошло не так,

#### Время от времени «чистить» вопросы по интересующей вас метке (меткам).

Для этого, используйте [встроенные фильтры поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), также поможет раздел [вопросов без ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) (фильтр `isanswered:no`, дополнительно, полезным фильтром будет дата создания сообщения, например, `created:1m..`). Вопросов по отдельной взятой метке не так много. Просматривая подобные вопросы, можно либо голосовать против, для автоматического удаления, либо за, при возможности публикуя ответ. Остальное сделает система!

Как мне кажется, проводить «коллективные субботники» имеет смысл в том случае, если [% отвеченных вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/956/6) начнет сильно падать (прямое свидетельство наличия большого количества плохих вопросов в базе знаний). Ежедневные потребности качества должна удовлетворить активная модерация сайта сообществом и интерес лидеров сообщества к вопросам по «их» меткам.

Answer (score 3):

Я лично идею поддерживаю.

Сейчас вообще праздники и я паралельно рефакторю свои пет-проекты, да поглядываю на so для разгрузки ума в паузах.

А чтение чата и проглядывание очереди проверки -- это такая ленивая операция, много ресурсов не съедает.

Тем более, что у меня 80% очереди просто пропускается -- я строго стараюсь пропускать сообщения по тегам, которые я не специалист (скажем, java или python).